# Opposite of `git push --mirror`? How do I get my repo back?

Tags: git, pull

I am having great success with `git push --mirror` to make backup copies to a bare repo. But after search on SO and elsewhere, I cannot find a way to clone the thing locally with **all branches.** I do not want to use `git clone` since I don't want my local repo to know about the bare repo. If I use `git pull` it only brings down the HEAD branch.

Guessing:

```
git pull /data/Dropbox/backup/that_stuff.git *
```

gets me nowhere, of course.

**How do I get the entire repo with all branches back again?** I realize I could probably just copy the bare repo to my .git directory, but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: So I guess the `git bundle` from 2 weeks ago is no longer to your liking? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository/2129286#2129286)

Comment: @VonC thanks so much for that. Although you did answer the question expertly, it turns out that it makes little sense to backup to a GIT bundle in a DropBox. It adds too much traffic (to the server) and has no advantage. MIrror is also way faster. Now if I could just resolve this one last problem :)

Comment: Just completed my answer with the right '`*`' you were looking for?

Comment: Almost a year later: bundles are the ONLY thing that  make sense on dropbox. If you use `git gc` the bundles are tiny, too.

Comment: @Yar could you elaborate on your last comment.. i'm in a similar situation, prefer bare repo over bundle... want to know your learning

Comment: @buffer, you cannot roll back a DIRECTORY in dropbox (last time I checked). You can only roll back files. Also, the internal pieces of a bare git repo will get screwed up if you try to sync from more than one computer to a dropbox. So either use unfuddle.com or use git bundles with dropbox, basically.

Comment: @Yar I've put all my git stuff in a truecrypt file container that gets uploaded as a binary to dropbox. Would that still be an issue if I try to sync it with multiple computers

Comment: @buffer, AFAIK that should be fine, since the truecrypt container is one big file, so Dropbox will not try to sync the individual pieces nor run into conflicts on individual files. That said, you should check out unfuddle.com which does have small free repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`git fetch`](http://gentoo.mirror.dkm.cz/pub/kernel.org/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-fetch.html) instead of `git pull`

Since `git pull` is there to fetch a branch and merge it to a local branch, it wouldn't make alot of sense trying to merge *all* remote branches to a local branches.

```
$ git fetch a-repo_url
```

The above command copies all branches from the remote `refs/heads/` namespace and stores them to the local `refs/remotes/remoteRpo/` namespace, **unless the `branch.<name>.fetch` option is used to specify a non-default refspec.**.
Try:

```
$ git fetch a-repo-url +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

could force fetching all heads for all branches.
See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch).

---

The OP [yar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8047/yar) reports:

```
git pull /data/Dropbox/backup/mjdj.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

works.

Comment: Tried that. GIT responds `* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
`... so it just gets that one.

Comment: Tried that last one with the asterisks... fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository

Comment: @yar: Maybe it needs a remote reference (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), but that would mean "making your local repo to know about the bare repo", which is not what you want.

Comment: Sorry this did it! Thanks `git pull /data/Dropbox/backup/mjdj.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` ... if you can update your answer I'll mark it

Comment: totally. that's what the songs are for.

Comment: Even more specific if you want *all* refs you can do git pull /data/Dropbox/backup/mjdj.git/ +refs/*:refs/*

Comment: My understanding is that `git fetch a-repo-url +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` will usually only work on a bare repo. Otherwise you'll get the error Yar mentions because [fetch cannot update the branch you're currently on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236743/git-refusing-to-fetch-into-current-branch/2236805#2236805). Using `pull` instead should work, but be prepared for merge conflicts unless you're sure it'll fast-forward.

Answer (score 1):

There's also (now?) git clone --mirror. But man says:

```
   --mirror
       Set up a mirror of the remote repository. This implies --bare.
```

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_clone_a_repository_with_all_remotely_tracked_branches.3F describes how to turn bare repo into non-bare.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with [git-copy](https://github.com/cybertk/git-copy).

```
git copy /data/Dropbox/backup/that_stuff.git that_stuff.git
```