# Git 'Refusing to fetch' error

Tags: git, fetch, egit

I'm not sure what has happened, but this command used to work up to now. I have a branch named `refactorizacion` checked out. If I run the command `git fetch`, it seems to work fine (no error is shown), but if I run `git fetch origin refactorizacion:refactorizacion`, it gives me the following error:

```
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/refactorizacion of non-bare repository
Unexpected end of command stream
```

This is also causing the `Team > Synchronize Workspace` command of `egit` in eclipse to show an error:

```
Fetch operation failed
Synchronization will be continued based on data that are currently in repository.
You can disable fetching changes before synchronization in preferences: Team > Git > Always launch fetch before synchronization
```

Comment: This previous SO question is probably relevant (not sure if it is an exact duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/q/2236743

Comment: @Hasturkun I saw that post, and I'm not sure it's the same case. This issue started recently, and even removing the project and cloning it again doesn´t solve it. Also, looking into .git/config, I have the following line `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, so I think it's a different scenario.

Comment: @carcaret I have the same error in Eclipse. I'm looking the other thread, but if you found any solution, I will be interested in knowing about it.

Comment: @madtyn Nothing so far, sorry