# Equivalent of updateInstead for git fetch -u

Tags: git, git-fetch

As [documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch--u) and [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19205680/27302) elsewhere, `git fetch` refuses to fetch the current branch unless you supply the `-u` option.

This behavior makes perfect sense in most cases, and is obviously the correct default. However, it is not the behavior I want. Instead, I would like something like what the configuration option `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` does: if the current working tree and index match `HEAD`, then allow the fetch and update working tree; otherwise, refuse the fetch with a similar message to the default. Is there any way to do this without writing my own porcelain command using `git fetch -u`?

---

The reason I want this, in case a better workflow is available, is that I am working on a number of projects stored in separate Git repositories. Most of them are just on the `dev` local branch, which has the `dev/master` remote branch as its upstream. When I am actually doing development, I do it on a branch named after whatever feature I’m working on, not the `dev` branch. I want all the remote branches available, so I need to do a `git fetch --all -p` regularly, and I additionally need to do a `git pull` in the projects I’m not building so they have the latest code. Because there are a lot of projects, the easiest way is to just loop through them in Bash and run `git fetch --all -p; git pull` on all of them. Unfortunately, that also runs `git pull` on the projects I’m currently making changes on, and that might lead to merge conflicts instead of just getting the latest dependencies.

Instead, I would like the projects I’m not currently working on have the working tree updated automatically; then I only need to run `git pull` on repositories I am currently working on. That way, I can run it only when it’s appropriate, and not worry about merge conflicts when I just want to build against the latest source of the dependent projects.

Comment: `git fetch` itself never updates the index and work-tree. I think you probably do need to write your own porcelain here. Note that `git-sh-setup` provides a way to test whether the index and work-tree are "clean" (match the `HEAD` commit), including submodules, without having to parse the output of `git status`. Note also that `git pull` is just `git fetch && git merge`, more or less, so instead of `git pull` you can test, then maybe-run `git merge`.

Comment: @torek I have not actually written my own Git commands before; is there a good guide to that anywhere?

Comment: There are plenty of *bad* ones :-) I'm not really sure of any good ones. Many parts of Git are written as shell scripts, though. Run `git --exec-path` and look in the resulting location, you'll find `stash` and `filter-branch` as examples of huge shell scripts. I'll add that if you write a script named `git-foo` and put it anywhere in your `$PATH`, `git foo` will run your script (with `git --exec-path` added at the front of `$PATH` so that you can `. git-sh-setup`, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I additionally need to do a `git pull` in the projects I’m not building so they have the latest code ... Unfortunately, that also runs `git pull` on the projects I’m currently making changes on

You can run `git pull --ff-only`, which fails immediately if there are some local commits.

Comment: I really should have thought of this myself and don’t know why I didn’t. It still doesn’t do exactly what I asked for, but it’s close enough and I think it does what I actually want.

Comment: It wasn’t quite that simple—I use pull-with-rebase by default because rebasing is expected where I work, and I needed to add `-c rebase.autoStash=no` to the command line—but now it works exactly as I wanted, and I can make an alias that does the fetch and that at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to use git hooks and run

```
git fetch -a
```

any time it is necessary

Comment: None of the hooks seem to be run on fetch, unless the ones which run on remote push also run on local fetch but I don’t see that documented anywhere.