# git: setting a single tracking remote from a public repo

Tags: git, tracking, fetch

I am confused with remote branches.

My local repo:

```
(local) ---A---B---C-master
```

My remote repo (called int):

```
(int) ---A---B---C---D---E-master
```

What I want to do is to setup the local repo's master branch to follow that of int.
Local repo:

```
(local) ---A---B---C---D---E-master-remotes/int/master
```

So that when int changes to:

```
(int) ---A---B---C---D---E---F-master
```

I can run `git pull` from the local repo's master and get

```
(local) ---A---B---C---D---E---F-master-remotes/int/master
```

Here's what I have tried:

1. `git fetch int` gets me all the branches of int into remote branches. This can get messy since int might have hundreds of branches.
2. `git fetch int master` gets me the commits, but no ref to it, only `FETCH_HEAD`. No remote branch either.
3. `git fetch int master:new_master` works but I don't want a new name every time I update, and no remote branch is setup.
4. `git pull int master` does what I want, but there is still no remote branch setup. I feel that it is ok to do so (that's the best I have now), but I read here and there that with the remote setup it is enough with `git pull`.
5. `git branch --track new_master int/master`, as per http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html . I get "not a valid object name: int/master". `git remote -v` does show me that int is defined and points at the correct location (1. worked). What I miss is the int/master branch, which is precisely what I want to get.
6. `git fetch in master:int/master`. Well, int/master is created, but is no remote.

So to summarize, I've tried some stuff with no luck. I would expect 2 to give me the remote branch to master in the repo int.

The solution I use now is option 3.

I read somewhere that you could change some config file by hand, but isn't that a bit cumbersome?

---

The "cumbersome" way of editting the config file did work:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = int
    merge = master
```

It can be done from command line:

```
$ git config branch.master.remote int

$ git config branch.master.merge master
```

Any reason why option 2 above wouldn't do that automatically?
Even in that case, `git pull` fetches all branches from the remote.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any current work in your working tree first.

Then try a (with Git1.7.0 or more):

```
git fetch int master
git branch --force -- set-upstream master int/master
```

Comment: I get: `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.` With a bit of trying I got to the point where I have a local tracking branch, but no remote tracking branch (i.e. they show in all green in gitk, no beige'n'green).

Comment: @Gauthier: err... but there is no such thing as a *local* tracking branch ;) Only *remote* tracking branch: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch

Comment: alright, I might have misunderstood something. What I mean is that when I tried a command that seemed to have an effect, I got: `Branch <branchname> set up to track local branch <int/branchname>.`, and it did not look like a remote.

Comment: `git fetch int master` gets the commits and give me `FETCH_HEAD` as a reference. How would the second line you wrote know where to set the upstream?

Comment: @Gauthier: not exactly: the second line is to force a local existing branch to follow a remote tracking branch you specify (composed of a remote repo name and a remote tracking branch name). So the second line knows where to set the upstream because you give in this line the exact reference of said upstream.