# In git, how do I check out a remote repository's remote branches?

Tags: git

I have a local repository cloned from a bare remote repository. The following command lists al the remote repository's branches.

```
$ git ls-remote <remote>

74bd3eb190edb39db04f6c0c4dbbb9e1e96bc6db    refs/remotes/test
85de54d6ae813c624b9623983e6b0a4948dae0fe    refs/remotes/trunk
```

I want to checkout and track that remote's remote branch *trunk*. How do I do that?

Note that this is different from checking out a remote repository's local branch.
This is how the remote repository looks like.

```
$ git branch -a

master
remotes/test
remotes/trunk
```

After running *git fetch < remote >* to fetch all of the remote repository's branches, I get this output in the local repository.

```
$ git branch -r

repo/HEAD -> repo/master
repo/master
```

Comment: Jefromi's and Chris's answers should be enough. I just add for reference the interesting SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fetch any ref from any remote (as long as the server is willing to give it to you). The key to fetching refs outside `refs/heads/` is to supply full ref paths that start with `refs/`. If desired, you can even pull from repositories that are not configured as remotes (*git fetch* can take a URL instead of a remote name).

By default, configured remotes will only fetch from the remote repository’s `refs/heads/` namespace, so they will not pick up anything inside `refs/remotes/`. But, you could refer to a ref inside it by using a complete ref like `refs/remotes/trunk` (`remotes/trunk` might also work, but might also be ambiguous).

If the fetched refspec does not specify a destination ref, it will be stored in the special FETCH_HEAD ref.

---

Fetch a repository’s `refs/remote/trunk` into FETCH_HEAD and check it out as a detached HEAD:

```
git fetch remote-name-or-url refs/remotes/trunk &&
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Same, but create a named, local branch instead of using a detached HEAD:

```
git fetch remote-name-or-url refs/remotes/trunk &&
git checkout -b trunk-from-remote FETCH_HEAD
```

Same, but directly into a local branch:

```
git fetch remote-name-or-url refs/remotes/trunk:trunk-from-remote &&
git checkout trunk-from-remote
```

If you are working with a configured remote, you can rewrite its `remote.<remote-name>.fetch` configuration and add an extra entry to automate fetching from both `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/`.

```
# fetch branchs of remote into remote-name/heads/*
git config remote.remote-name.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/remote-name/heads/*' &&
# fetch remotes of remote into remote-name/remotes/*
git config --add remote.remote-name.fetch '+refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/remote-name/remotes/*'
```

To avoid possible collisions, the above example configures fetch to store refs into disjoint namespaces (`…/heads/` and `…/remotes/`). You can pick different names if you like. If you are sure there will be no conflicts, you can even stuff them both directly under `refs/remotes/remote-name/`.

Comment: Can I set this up so it automatically pulls the remote's remote branch into a tracking local branch? Or am I better off making sure the remote have local tracking branches of its own, which I then track locally?

Comment: @Hans: I have rewritten the answer. I de-emphasized the “unconfigured remote” aspect that was probably not so important to you and added a bit at the end about automating the fetch.

Comment: How do I set up a local branch to track one of those remote remote branches? I do a proper 'git checkout -b trunk --track repo/remotes/trunk', but then a 'git pull repo' won't understand my branch.trunk.merge config. I have to do a 'git pull repo refs/remotes/trunk:refs/remotes/repo/remotes/trunk' for it to work.

Comment: I got it working. I had set up fetching the heads of the remote wrong, which probably meant git couldn't figure out what refs/remotes/trunk referred to.

Answer (score 6):

Good question! I know that this works; can't think of anything else that does off the top of my head:

```
git fetch origin refs/remotes/trunk
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
# or make a branch to check out
git checkout -b remote-trunk FETCH_HEAD
```

It's odd, by the way, that those remote refs aren't of the form `refs/remotes/<remote-name>/<branch-name>`... maybe I misunderstood the names, but the method does work.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I've found a satisfying solution to this.
Adding a remote sets up a refspec to fetch and pull its local heads. I set up another remote which I call /repo-remotes/ which fetch the remote's remote refs. The .git/config file ends up looking like this

```
[remote "repo"]
  url = ssh://git@<hostname>:<port>/repo
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/repo/*

[remote "repo-remotes"]
  url = ssh://git@<hostname>:<port>/repo
  fetch = +refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/repo-remotes/*
```

I can then do this.

```
$ git fetch repo-remotes
$ git checkout -b remote-trunk --track remotes/repo-remotes/trunk
```

Which sets up a local branch tracking the remote repository's remote branch /trunk/.

Comment: No need for a second remote, just add an extra fetch configuration.

Answer (score -1):

`git.exe checkout --track -b trunk refs/remotes/trunk`

Comment: The problem here is that the remote branch doesn't have local branches which track its remote branches.