# Git pull should ignore commits in unwanted branches

Tags: git, pull, git-branch

I'm using two local repositories/working trees for our project development:

- one for the release version (bug-fixes only) and
- one for the continuing development in the master.

Hence I don't need to switch between branches back and forth.
We only merge changes from the release branch to the master, but not the opposite.

Is it possible to configure my release-repository/working tree to not fetch changes from the master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify remote refspec for fetch, in order to only fetch what you want.
See:

- [ProGit The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).
- [In git, how do I check out a remote repository's remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036817/in-git-how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-repositorys-remote-branches) (for a practical example of `git config remote.remote-name.fetch` and `git --add config remote.remote-name.fetch`)

I am not sure, however, that you can specify "fetch everything but xxx".

If you don't want to fetch anything from your first (master) repo, maybe configuring the fetch directive with a non-existing branch name will server just that purpose.