# Specifying branch arguments to git fetch, merge, and push

Tags: git, branch, fetch, git-merge, git-fetch

If I am working on a branch of a repo, say `devel`, what is the difference between the following commands? In this case, I have already added an `upstream` remote:

```
$ git fetch upstream devel
From github.com:meteor/meteor
 * branch            devel      -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and

```
$ git fetch upstream 
remote: Counting objects: 500, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (230/230), done.
remote: Total 326 (delta 227), reused 187 (delta 90)
Receiving objects: 100% (326/326), 46.61 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (227/227), completed with 87 local objects.
From github.com:meteor/meteor
 * [new branch]      appconfig  -> upstream/appconfig
 * [new branch]      check-path -> upstream/check-path
   248ff08..4d44a4d  ctl-migrate -> upstream/ctl-migrate
   2c356d2..bfb8fd3  devel      -> upstream/devel
 * [new branch]      release-0.6.5 -> upstream/release-0.6.5
   64b95a4..c0014df  shark      -> upstream/shark
From github.com:meteor/meteor
 * [new tag]         release/0.6.5-rc11 -> release/0.6.5-rc11
 * [new tag]         release/0.6.5-rc12 -> release/0.6.5-rc12
```

How does fetch know what to get if no branch is specified?

Moreover, why is it that the merge command is

```
$ git merge upstream/devel
```

but if I want to push the changes to my fork, I need to say

```
$ git push origin devel
```

why is there a slash in one case but not the other?

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch upstream devel` is the same than:

```
 git fetch upstream refs/heads/devel
```

You don't provide a destination in your refspec, so the fetch update `FETCH_HEAD`, as explained in "[In git, how do I check out a remote repository's remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037062/6309)".
This is a  short-lived ref, used if you do a pull (fetch + merge).

`git fetch upstream` fetches everything, so there is no single ref to update.

---

`git merge` must specify the **source** of the merge, in your case the remote branch `devel` (`upstream/devel` since upstream is the name of your updated remote, updated after the fetch)
`git merge devel` would merge the local branch `devel` on the current branch... and if you are already on `devel`, that would result in a no-op.

But `git push` also specify the source, here a local branch `devel`, a remote destination `origin` (the "[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)") and the destination depends on the **[push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)**.
If `devel` is tracking a remote branch, and you currently are on `devel`, a simple `git push` is enough. See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more.

Comment: Isn't `git fetch upstream devel` more like `get fetch upstream refs/heads/devel` (note the *heads*)?  Remote refs should be under the remote name too, so it would be `refs/remote/upstream/devel`, if it were the right ref.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the comprehensive explanation and pointers. I'm sure this will be of value to others as well because so far I just type branch arguments randomly and pray that it is doing the right thing :)