# Deleting remote branches?

Tags: git

When I run git branch -a, it prints out like this, for ex:

```
branch_a
remotes/origin/branch_a
```

Few questions:

1. What does branch_a indicate?
2. What does remotes/origin/branch_a indicate?
3. How do I delete remotes/origin/branch_a?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git/3046478#3046478 help for 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `branch_a` indicates that you have a local branch called `branch_a`.
2. `remotes/origin/branch_a` indicates that you have a remote called `origin`, and you are tracking the `branch_a` within the `origin` remote. This isn't necessarily associated with your own `branch_a`, but it probably is (`git branch -a` doesn't say).
3. Since the `remotes/origin/branch_a` is a remote tracking branch, it's required if your own `branch_a` is set up to track the remote. If not, then deleting the `origin` remote should remove it, or you might be able to simply `git branch -d remotes/origin/branch_a`.

Comment: This command worked for me: git branch -d -r origin/branch_a. I had already deleted local, so used that command to get rid of remote.

Answer (score 0):

1. branch_a is the local 'tracking branch' for the remote branch_a.
2. remotes/origin/branch_a is a remote branch, living on the origin repository.
3. `git push origin :branch_a` removes the remote branch from the origin repository, despite looking a bit hackish. If you want to remove branch_a, run `git branch -d branch_a`.

Comment: i downticked this because my understanding is that branch_a is not a tracking branch - it's just a local branch .... if branch_a is mapped to remote origin branch_a then git will auto-create locally-cached tracking-branch remotes/origin/branch_a