# How do I stop pushing to multiple remote branches in git? (aka, How do I untrack remote git branches?)

Tags: git, git-branch, remote-branch

Tried to use what's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3046436/1028230), but that doesn't solve things for me.

I've got a local repo in git, cloned from a remote repo, `development`.  I branch locally to play around with a new feature in a branch called `newBranchName` and call `git push origin newBranchName` to set up the new branch on the remote repo.

Now when I try to push, git seems to be pushing my `newBranchName` local branch into everything the old branch tracked as well.  I want that to stop.

Here's an extended sample of what I mean.  I'm going to create a local branch, add a file, commit locally, then push to a new branch on the remote server.  So far, so good.

```
Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (oldBranch)
$ git branch testingStuff

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (oldBranch)
$ git checkout testingStuff
Switched to branch 'testingStuff'

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ vim test.txt

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ git add test.txt

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ git commit -a
[testingStuff 11468d8] Testing git; can trash this branch.
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ git push origin testingStuff
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 299 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://url/to/remote/repo.git
 * [new branch]      testingStuff -> testingStuff
```

Now, I'll edit that test.txt file, commit the change, and push.  This is what confuses me.

```
Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ vim test.txt

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ git commit -a
[testingStuff 2be7063] more testing git
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 276 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://url/to/remote/repo.git
   11468d8..2be7063  testingStuff -> testingStuff
 ! [rejected]        oldBranch -> remoteTrackedByOldBranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://url/to/remote/repo.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I want to continue pushing to `testingStuff` remotely, but want to stop pushing to `remoteTrackedByOldBranch` when I type `git push`.  I don't want to delete any branch -- seems a number of answers to similar questions suggest deleting rather than untracking.  Nor do I want to know how to push to a specific branch only by explicitly naming it in the git push command.  Too many muscle-memory mistakes that way.  I want `git push` to push to `origin/testingStuff` only.

I've already unsmartly (a word which proves itself) butchered my .git/config trying to accomplish this, and it's still pushing to `remoteTrackedByOldBranch`.

**EDIT:** Here's what my .git/config file looks like after doing the above:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = http://url/to/remote/repo.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "oldBranch"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/oldBranch
```

Nothing about the `testingStuff` branch in there.

**EDIT:**  `git branch -avv` output:

```
Administrator@BOXEN /path/to/working/dir (testingStuff)
$ git branch -avv
  master                                 721aa61 initial setup
  projectFork1                           e132f5f Fixed Construction grid labels getting sliced.
  projectFork2                           1d20317 initial load
  oldBranch                              1d20317 initial load
* testingStuff                           192f622 Still testing
  remotes/origin/HEAD                    -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/empty                   ec1c694 initial setup
  remotes/origin/joeUserFork1            771f43e Initial Load
  remotes/origin/master                  721aa61 initial setup
  remotes/origin/projectFork1            e132f5f Fixed Construction grid labels getting sliced.
  remotes/origin/oldBranch               1d20317 initial load
  remotes/origin/joeUserFork2            dc605e8 What was sent initially.
  remotes/origin/testingStuff            192f622 Still testing
  remotes/origin/upload_master           0d8c440 Initial Load
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Only push the branch you're on**

By default, git will push all of your tracking branches whenever you issue a git push with no arguments. to make it *only* push the branch you're on

```
git config push.default upstream # git 1.7.10
git config push.default tracking # older vesions use "tracking" instead of "upstream"
```

if you want git to always work like that - you can use the --global switch or simply edit your [~/.gitconfig](https://github.com/AD7six/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig#L30) file to suit.

**Stop tracking a remote branch**

git's config is just a file. Quite often the easiest way to investigate and or fix your git config - is simply to open your .git/config file and edit it

e.g. if you have a section like this in your .git/config file:

```
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
    rebase = true
```

and you make it:

```
[branch "develop"]
    rebase = true
```

your branch nolonger tracks anything. You can also just delete the whole section and git will act the same.

Comment: Well, that's the strange part.  In config, I have `[branch master]`, and (in the scenario above), `[branch oldBranch]`, but nothing for `testingStuff`, my new branch.  I'm assuming your `develop` should represent `testingStuff` in my scenario, above. I don't have `rebase=true` in there, but I'm assuming that's just particular to your workflow.  I'll paste my config into my question.

Comment: `$ git config set push.default upstream` gives
`error: key does not contain a section: set`.  I'll Google around.

Comment: "set" was a mistake - I assume you immediately found e.g. [this](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/)

Comment: Yep, sorry -- `git config push.default upstream` followed by `git push` and an error, followed by `git push --set-upstream origin testingStuff` to explicitly set an upstream branch, then `git push` works just like I'd like.  I'd still like to get larsks' answer to work, though.

Answer (score 3):

The tracking relationship with a remote branch is maintained in the `branch.<BRANCHNAME>.remote` and `branch.<BRANCHNAME>.merge` configuration items associated with a particular branch.  You can see the current configuration like this:

```
git config --get-regexp 'branch.remoteTRackedByOldBranch.*'
```

And you can delete the configuration like this:

```
git config --remove-section branch.remoteTrackedByOldBranch
```

[Note that this will remove *all* the configuration associated with this branch, but it is unlikely there is anything other than the `remote` and `merge` settings.  You can obviously accomplish the same thing by hand-editing the `.git/config` file.]

After this change `git push` should no longer attempt to push that branch to a remote.

Comment: Even after removing everything headed by [branch X] (master & oldBranch), I still get `! [rejected]        oldBranch -> remoteTrackedByOldBranch (non-fast-forward)`.  At what point does config get refreshed?  I've opened new terms for git (using git with MINGW32 for Windows) and nothing changes.  The first command, `git config --get-regexp 'branch.remoteTRackedByOldBranch.*'` does return nothing, fwiw.

Comment: What does `git branch -avv` show?  Also, does the `.git/config` posted in your answer reflect the current state of the configuration?  If not, maybe update it and add the output of the `branch` command.

Comment: The "hypothetical scenario" approach and "real life" are conflating a little in the results, but I've posted the `-avv` output with a little name cleaning.  The .git/config was changed only to hide paths.

Comment: In your example above, I note that your `config` file still shows the configuration for `oldBranch` (the last three lines).  That would lead `git push` to try sending `oldBranch`.

Comment: No no, my fault.  It is not the post-edit state of the config.  That's the state at the end of my scenario, before the editing described in the first comment to your answer.  After your answer, I blasted `[branch master]` and `[branch oldBranch]` and the lines below them (merge and remote) completely, and, as above, still had the `! [rejected]` issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Not sure why editing `config` didn't work as expected.  I'll revisit when it bugs me, but for now AD7six' route forces the behavior we're setting up The Right Way here.