# How do I clean up completely after SVN -> Git migration?

Tags: git, git-svn

I've migrated a repo from SVN to Git using `svn2git` and am happy with everything apart from one thing. How can I remove the `remotes/svn/trunk` branch that shows in `git branch -a`:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/svn/trunk
```

I cleaned up after `svn2git` by doing the following:

```
git config --remove-section svn-remote.svn
git config --remove-section svn
rm -rf .git/svn
```

But I still have the `remotes/svn/trunk` sitting there! I get this if I grep the `.git` directory for `svn`:

```
$ grep -R svn .git
.git/info/refs:e6dd7a08d86d9b0944891755602b25ce12d30bb0 refs/remotes/svn/trunk
Binary file .git/objects/pack/pack-10cdd522d8f0fcc9b30efeddbdad3d0281c1e6da.pack matches
.git/packed-refs:e6dd7a08d86d9b0944891755602b25ce12d30bb0 refs/remotes/svn/trunk
```

Am I safe to go into those files and remove the references or is there a cleaner way to get rid of that old cruft?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deleting the remote tracking branch would be a good start:

```
git branch -d -r svn/trunk
```

Other advices are available at "[How do you stop tracking a remote branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git)".
But to really clean, you may have to do other operations (based on `git gc` for instance) as mentioned in "[How to remove unreferenced blobs from my git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo)".

Comment: Ugh, yeh that's the one. Should have known that really! I get slightly confused still with what a remote tracking branch is. Still very new to git!

Comment: @mattjgalloway : yes, it can be confusing ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch can help making this "remote tracking" business a bit clearer.

Comment: After trying `git branch -d -r svn/trunk`, I get "error: remote branch 'svn/trunk' not found.", yet it still shows in SourceTree under Remotes... Ideas?

Comment: @Saran what does `git remote -v` and `git br -avvv` return?

Comment: `git remote -v` returns nothing and `git branch -avvv` returns my branches w/o the (remote) svn/trunk one.

Comment: @Saran so your error message is coherent with your current local repo. A `svn2git` is supposed to declare a remote repo.

Comment: @VonC strange :) One more question: as mentioned in the question from mattjgalloway, is it safe to remove [svn-remote "svn"] and [svn] entries from the projects git config file in order to remove the remotes/Subversion entry I see in SourceTree?

Comment: @Saran it should be safe. But one technique I use when I don't like the internal state of a repo is... to clone it: I check I can still work from the clone (which shouldn't include any extra remote data this time). That way, I don't touch whatever repo I currently have: I clone and hack on the clone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40566/discussion-between-saran-and-vonc)

Comment: @Saran: Had the same problem and @VonC's solution to make a local clone (`git clone old_path duplicate`) worked!