# git pull error :error: remote ref is at but expected

Tags: git, pull, git-pull

**Full message:**

```
error: Ref refs/remotes/origin/user is at 3636498c2ea7735fdcedc9af5ab3c8689e6abe77 but expected a21359c6cc2097c85775cde6a40105f4bd7100ec
From github.com:{github project url}
 ! a21359c..6273ffc  user -> origin/user  (unable to update local ref)
```

Comment: Apparently someone rewrote history of the repository by `git push --force`. Try to run `git pull --force`.

Comment: Gives same error with git push --force

Comment: Answer to this question resolved this error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git

Comment: open .git/packed-refs in a text editor, replace a21359c6cc2097c85775cde6a40105f4bd7100ec with 3636498c2ea7735fdcedc9af5ab3c8689e6abe77 and save. problem solved.

Answer (score 311):

## Permanent Fix

`git update-ref -d` resolved my instance of this error, e.g.

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/user
```

Note that this doesn't impact remote.

In my case, a subsequent `git fetch` fetched that branch again, and following git fetches/pulls no longer gave the error "remote ref is at but expected".

## If that doesn't work, a temporary fix:

Note also that if you don't care about the branch in question (e.g. you just want to update master, not origin/user), a `git pull` workaround is to fetch then just merge the particular branch you care about, e.g.

```
git fetch # may give an error for a particular branch, but other branches will still be successfully fetched
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution because it solves the problem without touching remote.

Comment: This just moved me further into the swap. Doing `git rebase --continue` afterwards I get `fatal: Needed a single revision. Cannot read HEAD`

Comment: Best answer (permanent fix).  You are not touching remote and a subsequent git pull gets the branch again.

Comment: The issue specific to me was that all the remote branch names were lower case, 'feature/branch' but a new one was introduced with capital case 'Feature/branch'. Changing the remote to 'feature/branch', then deleting refs/remotes/origin and doing a git pull fixed the issue for me on a mac.

Answer (score 304):

If you are running git under a file system that is not case sensitive (Windows or OS X) this will occur if there are two branches with the same name but different capitalisation, e.g. `user_model_changes` and `User_model_changes` as both of the remote branches will match the same tracking ref.

Delete the wrong remote branch (you shouldn't have branches that differ only by case) and then `git remote prune origin` and everything should work

Comment: thanks for answer. This wasn't the issue with this error. I already found the solution to this issue and posted in comment below the question.

Comment: Helps for Mac OS X as well (the default filesystem is case insensitive).

Comment: yes, the case-insensitive issue on Windows caused the problem. I fixed it by manually removing the ref in `.git\refs\remotes\origin` folder and then `git pull` again.

Comment: and for those who dont know where .git folder will be.. it will be created inside your Project/workspace folder :D

Comment: This is a git bug.(At least the error message is wrong). I hope someone can report this bug to the git project. It looks difficult for me to report bug to the git project. https://github.com/git/git

Comment: how does one "Delete the wrong remote branch " ?  `git branch -d a_remote_branch_name` says that the branch is not found

Answer (score 90):

Use the below two commands one by one.

```
git gc --prune=now

git remote prune origin
```

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: This works for me but when I do another git pull this issue comes up again

Comment: @Jojin Same as you. And I finally chose the way  Prakash Saravanan provided

Comment: This should be rated higher than the suggestion to edit git files :)

Comment: The solution worked for me as well. Can you please explain what these commands exactly do, and why we need to use these commands?

Comment: Thank you, this was the only answer that worked for me using the git command line.

Answer (score 89):

Just delete the folders and files under `\.git\refs\remotes\origin`.
Works, when u don't have unpushed changes.

Comment: This might not work if your remote ref is 'packed' and therefore not in refs/remotes/** @JDiMatteo's solution should work then still

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: When I do this, and then do a pull, all those deleted files under `\.git\refs\remotes\origin` returns back and in the subsequent pull, I get the same error. It is a cycle. What I did was to just delete the local copy and clone a fresh copy. That worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me !!!

Answer (score 75):

I ran this to solve the problem:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution fix for me. Could you please explain bit more about the solution you provided.

Comment: basically it's just a git garbage collector tool so it erases anything that is not in sync but is on the local computer for caching purposes

Answer (score 13):

I had to remove my **branch** from my command line at:

```
.git\refs\remotes\{my remote}\{**my branch**}
```

and then manually doing:

```
git pull [remote_name] [branch_name]
```

I was able to pull the changes.

Note: I was using *SourceTree* and was unable to do the pull.

Comment: Ultimately I renamed my remotes: I had two remotes "Bitbucket/staging" and "bitbucket/staging" in my SourceTree history but only "Bitbucket" appeared on the command line when doing: git remote -v. So I renamed Bitbucket to bitbucket and the conflict finally disappeared, hope this helps most likely SourceTree users.

Comment: I also had to remove the branch from `.git\packed-refs` before it was fixed for me.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately GIT commands like prune and reset or push didn't work for me. Prune worked once and then the issue returned.

The permanent solution which worked for me is to edit a git file manually. Just go to the project's .git folder and then open the file packed-refs in a text editor like Notepad++. Then navigate to the row with the failing branch and update its guid to the expected one.

If you have a message like:

> error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/branch_xxx': is at 425ea23facf96f51f412441f41ad488fc098cf23 but expected 383de86fed394ff1a1aeefc4a522d886adcecd79

then in the file find the row with `refs/remotes/origin/feature/branch_xxx`. The guid there will be the expected (2nd) one - `383de86fed394ff1a1aeefc4a522d886adcecd79`. You need to change it to the real (1st) one - `425ea23facf96f51f412441f41ad488fc098cf23`.

Repeat for the other failing branches and you'll be good to proceed. Sometimes after re-fetch I had to repeat for the same branches which i already 'fixed' earlier. On re-fetch GIT updates guids and gives you the latest one.

Anyways the issue isn't a show stopper. The branch list gets updated. This is rather a warning.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me. After the fix I never saw the error again.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the refs being out of sync.

Answer (score 8):

Run the following commands in the following order

```
git gc --prune=now
git remote prune origin
git pull
```

Answer (score 6):

**Clearer Steps**

1. in terminal

   ```
   cd /.git/refs/remotes/origin
   ```
2. do  `ls`, you will see some **branches** and **HEAD**
3. Remove the branch you think has the problem

   ```
   rm branchname
   ```
4. If it did not work, delete all **branches/HEAD**

   - you may wana pull

Hope it works now.

Comment: is this essentially the same as `git update-ref -d <branchname>`?

Answer (score 6):

A hard reset will also resolve the problem

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Have you selected a best answer?

Comment: this is the best and easiest answer  i think.   git reset --hard

Comment: While this will resolve the problem, I'd also like to caution users that executing this command when you have local commits in the branch that are not yet pushed to remote will essentially wipe out those local commits (however, these can still be retrieved using git reflog for a period of time)

Answer (score 6):

I have tried multiple options but no option worked for me. Below command worked for me. Putting it here, if it can help people incase other options does not work.

**git pull -p**

> -p
> --prune
> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a --tags option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then they are also subject to pruning. Supplying --prune-tags is a shorthand for providing the tag refspec.

--Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--p

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me.
In your terminal: `git remote prune origin`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem which was caused because I resetted to an older commit even though I already pushed to the remote branch.

I solved it by deleting my local branch then checking out the origin branch `git checkout origin/my_branch` and then executing `git checkout my_branch`

Comment: This is one of the best ways to easily get rid of other hassles. And you always get a fresh start. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue and my solution is given below:

Step 1:

1. Please run this command first.

   **git gc --Prune=now**

Step 2:

1. If there is no error after running Step 1 command then run this below command in your terminal.

   **git remote Prune Origin**

I hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now

Comment: does not work on git 2.36.0 says "unknown option 'expire=now'"

Answer (score 0):

Same case here, but nothing about comments posted it's right in my case, I have only one branch (master) and only use Unix file system, this error occur randomly when I run git fetch --progress --prune origin and branch is ahead or 'origin/master'. Nobody can commit, only 1 user can do push.

NOTE: I have a submodule in acme repository, and acme have new submodule changes (new commits), I need first do a submodule update with git submodule update.

```
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Payload POST received from Bitbucket
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Exec: cd /var/www/html/acme
---------------------
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Updating Git code for all branches
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Exec: /usr/bin/git checkout --force master
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
[2014-07-29 13:58:37]   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Command returned some errors:
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Already on 'master'
---------------------
[2014-07-29 13:58:37] Exec: /usr/bin/git fetch --progress --prune origin
[2014-07-29 13:58:39] Command returned some errors:
[2014-07-29 13:58:39] error: Ref refs/remotes/origin/master is at 8213a9906828322a3428f921381bd87f42ec7e2f but expected c8f9c00551dcd0b9386cd9123607843179981c91
[2014-07-29 13:58:39] From bitbucket.org:acme/acme
[2014-07-29 13:58:39]  ! c8f9c00..8213a99  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
---------------------
[2014-07-29 13:58:39] Unable to fetch Git data
```

To solve this problem (in my case) simply run first git push if your branch is ahead of origin.

Comment: Your answer here only relates to the fact that your local repository is ahead of the origin after a new commit. This is the natural state of a local git commit operation and does not relate to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have my own fix. Because I'm using source tree, this error happens because someone create a new branch. The source tree is confused about this. After I press "Refresh" button beside the "remote branch to pull" combobox, it seems that sourcetree has updated the branch list, and now I can pull successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue , I just deleted the remote branch and created new branch from the master and merged my changes from old feature branch to new feature branch . Now i tried pull and push requests its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to pull from my Git repo and getting same error as mentioned above. In My case, I performed steps as right clicked on the project folder -> clicked on settings -> clicked on Remote -> clicked on remove button -> provide details for configuration Remote: "origin" , URL:"" in this setting page. -> then clicked on 'Add New/Save' button-> clicked ok.

After above changes, I am able to pull/fetch my desired branch successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, executing git pull command within the IntelliJ IDEA (the IDE) will report this error, but when I start a terminal, I notice that git is on an unfinished rebasing process. So executing `git rebase --abort` and `git pull --force` fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in naming of branches when I work in Windows environment. Developer used two branches with the same name but different letter case:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2KxN.png]

Windows suggest that Lis-1086 and lis-1086 the same in `.git\refs\remotes\origin\feature\Lis-1086` and don't fetch the second branch. I suppose there  no problem in Linux environment

So I've got into gitlab and remove unused (both) branches. Then git pull had worked correctly without any other changes like `-p`, `--hard`

Answer (score -2):

After searching constantly, this is the solution that worked for me which entails unsetting/removing the Upstream

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```