# Git - " cannot lock ref is at " on git Pull

Tags: git

I see the below error when i do git pull on my terminal in intellij.
The project is constantly updated by several developers and i'm sure something is out of sync, but cannot figure out what that is.

```
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/SOMETHING-1234': is at e131d16d4b4b8c32e3d16d28559baf2e4d18b012 but expected 090916d9bee669944a2ea55703f25a4ebee7d51a
 ! 090916d9b..e131d16d4  feature/SOMETHING-1234 -> origin/feature/SOMETHING-1234  (unable to update local ref)
```

What could possibly be the issue here ? How do i fix this ?
The feature branch above has been created by another developer i don't want to delete it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git pull error :error: remote ref is at but expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796580/git-pull-error-error-remote-ref-is-at-but-expected)

Comment: Torek's answer sounds more convincing so ill go with that. Thanks for pointing the duplicate though.

Comment: `git remote prune origin` (as linked duplicate main solution suggests) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Note: this *is* a duplicate, but the other question has no accepted answer, so I am posting one here.  The problem occurs because someone created a branch (`feature/SOMETHING-1234` in your example above) that differs *only in case* from a name that your Git already picked up.  For instance, you might have `feature/something-1234` or `FEATURE/SOMETHING-1234`, while they now have `feature/SOMETHING-1234`.

Git believes that names that differ only in case, such as `a` vs `A`, are *different names*.  This works correctly *some of the time*.  It fails on some operating systems<sup>1</sup> *some of the time*.  When it fails—as it is in your case—you get odd symptoms like the one you are seeing now.

In this case, one way to *possibly* cure it is to remove the (local) file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/something-1234`—you can type it in in all-lower-case, regardless of whatever parts have upper-case; see footnote 1—just before you run `git fetch`.  Your Git will re-create this with the case supplied by the other Git.  Note, however, that the problem may well come back, perhaps even immediately, especially if the other Git is one that *can* store *both* names (e.g., both `feature/something-1234` *and* `feature/SOMETHING-1234`) at all times.

To cure the problem more permanently, it is necessary to *delete* the duplicate-except-for-case name in the *other* Git.  That is, if a GitHub Git has branches named both `feature/SOMETHING-1234` and `feature/something-1234`, you and your colleagues must get together and agree on which of these two names to keep and which one to delete.  Then you can and should delete the "wrong" one and make sure never to re-create it.

(There is ongoing work in Git that will fix this problem for everyone, I think, but it's not released yet.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, this is a *file-system specific problem* these days, rather than an OS-specific problem.  However, it normally occurs on Windows and MacOS file systems, which are set up to be case-preserving but case-folding.  That is, if you create a file named `ReadMe`, then ask the system to open a file named `readme` or `README`, it opens the existing `ReadMe` file.

Other file systems—including the usual ones used on Linux hosts, such as those running GitHub—treat `readme`, `ReadMe`, and `README` as *three different files*.  So these systems can and will store all three files at the same time.  The case-folding file systems on Windows and MacOS literally *can't* store three such files.

Git currently uses a hybrid scheme, in which *refs* or *references*—branch, tag, and other names—are stored in one or both of two places: a simple plain-text table file that has every reference on a line along with its hash ID, or, one hash ID per file, with the file's *name* matching the reference name.  When the refs differ only in case, the per-file storage mechanism only works correctly on file systems that can store both names.  The one-big-file mechanism works correctly even on the usual Windows and MacOS file system, though, as all the entries are just in a file named `.git/packed-refs`.

Note that if a ref appears in both `.git/packed-refs` *and* an individual file, the individual file version overrides the `.git/packed-refs` version.

Comment: I had a similar issues, but instead of deleting .git/refs/remotes/origin/feature, I just changed the folder name from Feature to feature.

Comment: Removing the duplicate (wrong case) entry from packed-refs helped me.

Answer (score 12):

I opened terminal and use following command and works for me. After writing this command , this keep pulling all branches without error

`git remote prune origin`

[image]