# Opposite of git branch --set-upstream

Tags: git, branch

I would like to stop tracking certain branches.
I set up tracking using `git branch --set-upstream foo origin/foo`.

How do I undo this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the below:

```
git config --unset branch.<branch>.remote
git config --unset branch.<branch>.merge
```

Answer (score 50):

In git 1.8, which will be released shortly, you'll be able to do:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

However, for the moment you would have to do [as manojlds suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914311/223092), and use two `git config --unset` commands.

Comment: And, ironically, `git branch --set-upstream` is being deprecated.

Comment: BTW, is there a source for the unset option? I don't see it in the relnotes.

Comment: @manjolds: it was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b84869ef14081b298a4ab825219221ccfcb2a3ba), and is in v1.8.0-rc0, v1.8.0-rc1 and v1.8.0-rc2

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you want to remove the association between the local and remote branch...
I think one of the easiest way should be by editing the config file (.git/config).

[You can find something related to your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git?rq=1)

> To remove the association between the local and remote branch, and
>   delete the local branch, run:
>
> ```
> git config --unset branch.<branch>.remote
> git config --unset branch.<branch>.merge
> git branch -d <branch>
> ```