# "Could not get advertised Ref for branch..." error when pulling in a git repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

When trying to pull (Team|Pull from the context menu) in a git repository in Eclipse I get `Could not get advertised Ref for branch refs/heads/develop` error. I guess that's because remote branch named `develop` was deleted in the meantime. Branch `develop` is currently checked out.

How to fix this?
Can I configure git and/or Eclipse so that I don't get this error next time some other remote branch gets deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mention in "[How do you stop tracking a remote branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/6309)", you can unset the associated remote tracking branch with:

```
git config --unset branch.develop.remote
git config --unset branch.develop.merge
```

It is certainly possible to edit the fetch/push specifications of a branch in EGit (see "[Direct Fetch and Push Support](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Direct_Fetch_and_Push_Support) "), but I find it so much quicker through the git CLI (command line interface).

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error, and so I made sure my `.git/config` file had the following:

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

That made EGit happy.

Comment: This made my EGit also happy :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I messed up with branch name - can't pull despite of the fact that the branch was present in origin.

I "solved" it by switching to another branch and then pull.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by

`git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after removed the remote branch and pull the corresponding branch on local, so the resolve solution is easy:

- switch to valid branch then pull
- or push local branch to remote
- or set another remote branch for local branch
- ...  any such operations can help

Answer (score 1):

I had solved by make sure my `.git/config` file had the following (like @jake-toronto said):

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/mybranch
```

And also make sure mybranch appears in:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://XXXX.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/mybranch:refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check once you have added proper username/password.
2. To Change username/password in eclipse goto (There is some other way as well to change username/password):
   `Right click on your project -> Team -> fetch from upstream -> Configure -> Change button (next to URL) -> Update username/password -> Save & fetch it.`
3. Now try to push your changes by:
   `Right click on your project -> Team -> Push branch 'branch name'`