# How to stop divergent branch warnings in Git?

Tags: git, heroku, git-flow

I use [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) so I work on a `develop` branch and only push releases to `master`. After creating a remote (named `heroku`) on my Heroku account, I started pushing my local `develop` branch to `master`, mostly for verification:

```
 git push heroku develop:master
```

Now that my app is more mature, I only push `master` releases. However, Git indicates that my local `develop` branch and the remote `master` branch have diverged:

```
Your branch and 'heroku/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 11 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

How can I stop these warnings without merging the remote `master` branch into the local `develop` branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been feebly trying to remove the merged commits directly on the `heroku` remote. However, the problem is that the local `develop` branch was set to track the remote `master` branch when I first pushed it:

```
% git remote show heroku
* remote heroku
  Fetch URL: [REDACTED]
  Push  URL: [REDACTED]
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop merges with remote master
    master  merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

So all I needed to do was to have the local `develop` branch **stop** tracking the remote branch. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/225386), I removed the tracking branch and unset it as upstream:

```
# On branch develop
% git branch -d -r heroku/master
% git branch --unset-upstream
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the warnings, you need to stop your local `develop` branch from tracking the remote `master` branch.

To remove the association between your local and remote branch:

```
git config --unset branch.develop.remote
git config --unset branch.develop.merge
```

This should stop the warnings.