# Chekout branch from a fork on git without tracking

Tags: git, branch, fork

I own a git repo on github. A collaborator forked it and created branch `A`. I want to checkout that branch into a branch on my local machine called `testA`. I don't want to track it, I just need get the files.

Comment: If you hate tracking all that much you can get rid of it after following VonC's answer. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/697012) shows you how to remove tracking.

Answer (score 2):

You need first to add a remote to that fork:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote add fork /url/to/fork
```

Then you can fetch and create your branch:

```
git fetch fork
git checkout -b testA fork/A --no-track
```