# Synchronizing single file between two Git repos

Tags: git

I faced with a trivial situation but it seems like it have no simple solution: I want to synchronize a single config file between two `git` repositories. It even could be a one-way interaction: origin is stored in project `A` and is tracked inside project `B`

I'm aware of `git submodule` concept, but submoduling of the large repository in the smaller one only for the sake of a single file seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add one repo as a remote and fetch.
Then you can [checkout a file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364223/6309) (including a [remote tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/6309) one)

```
git remote add repoA A
git fetch repoA
git checkout repoA/master -- file
```

(Assuming you want the file from `A` into repo `B`)

Comment: Note that this requires that the path for the file is the same in both repositories.

Answer (score 2):

If both repos are kept on the same machine;

- Keep the file in the project `A` repo. There is where its history is recorded.
- Put a link to the file in project `B`'s repo.
- Add that link to `B`'s `.gitignore`.