# Compare files in git remote vs local

Tags: git

I am new to Git and I have tried playing around with a few features.

What does

```
git diff HEAD...origin master
```

vs.

```
git diff origin master
```

do?

They seem to give me entirely different results.

Perhaps it's good to note that I do have a `origin/master` that is different from `origin master`.

Shouldn't it all mean the same thing?

Comment: This must be a duplicate. What is a good canonical?

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing together several different Git concepts.  Admittedly, these Git concepts all have *very* similar names: remotes, branches, and remote-tracking branches.  (Git's nomenclature gets even worse, as there's the concept of *tracking*, which is not the same as a *remote-tracking branch*, and when you have one branch tracking another, the tracked branch is called the *upstream*, which is not the same as using a remote as an upstream, or using a remote named `upstream`.  If you're not confused, you're doing way better than I was, or most people. :-) )

So, let's back this thing up a bit and define all these.

#### Definition: branch

First, we have *branches*.  The word "branch" in Git is actually ambiguous: it can refer to a branch *name*, like `master`, or it can refer to a *series of commits*, starting from the tip-most commit on a branch, and working backwards through time.  In other words, if you casually say "blah mumble branch `master` yada yada", it's not immediately clear whether you mean the branch *name* `master`, or the series of commits formed by starting with the commit that `master` names and working backwards through history.

It's usually clear from context though, and if not, you can use "branch name" and "branch structure" to distinguish them.  A branch name is just a word like `master`, except that to be a current and valid branch name, it has to be a name Git knows about, that Git will show if you run `git branch`.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Note that a branch *name* can translate directly into the tip-most commit of the branch *structure*.  The `git diff` command uses this quite a bit, as we'll see in a moment.  To see how a branch name turns into a commit ID, use `git rev-parse`.  This command simply looks at things, so it's safe to use any time.  Try it out now:

```
$ git rev-parse master
```

and:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
```

and if you have some other branches, try passing their names to `git rev-parse`.  (Then try `git branch -vv and compare the abbreviated commit IDs you see in its output, to what you got from`git rev-parse`.)

#### Definition: remote

A *remote* is just a name, like `origin`.  In this respect it is much like a branch name.  The difference is that a *remote* name is stored in a different place from branch names, and Git will show you your remote names if you run `git remote`.  Besides this, a remote name gives you two things: the ability to run `git fetch` and `git push` without writing out a big long URL—Git keeps the big long URL under the name of the remote—and the ability to have *remote-tracking branches*.

#### Definition: remote-tracking branch

A remote-tracking branch is (yet again!) just a name, but it starts out with the name of a remote, like `origin`, then has a slash, and then has the name of a branch "as seen on <s>TV</s> the remote".<sup>1</sup>  Thus, you'll see names like `origin/master`, which are typical remote-tracking branch names.

There is one key difference between your (regular, local) branch names and remote-tracking branches:  Your Git updates your branches as you work with them: you check them out, use `git commit` to add commits to them, use `git merge` to add merge commits to them, and so on.  You can `git checkout` a branch, and then `git status` will say that you are "on" the branch, e.g., `on branch master`.

Your Git *does not* update your remote-tracking branches this way.  In fact, you can't get "on" them at all.  Instead, when you run `git fetch origin`—here's where you use the remote name, `origin`—your Git looks up the URL from the remote, calls up another Git using that URL, and has a little conversation with it.  Your Git gets, from their Git, a list of all *their* branches—branch *names*, I should say.  Then your Git gets from their Git any of the *commits* that they have, that you don't: their branch structure.

Once your Git has their branch structure, it sets your remote-tracking branch (a name) to point to the tip-most commit, the same as their branch name does in their Git.  Your Git does this for each of their branches.  This way, after `git fetch origin`, your remote-tracking branches now keep track, for you, of where *their* branches were, the last time your Git caught up with their Git.

Your Git constructs your remote-tracking branch names by sticking your remote name (`origin`) in front of their branch names (`master`).  That's why your remote-tracking branch is `origin/master`: their branch name is `master`.

#### Definition: `HEAD`

The name `HEAD`, in Git, is pretty special.  (In fact, it's so special that if you manage to remove the file `.git/HEAD` somehow, Git will stop believing that your Git repository *is* a Git repository!)  However, normally `HEAD` really just contains the *name of a branch*.  For instance, if you're on branch `master`, the special `HEAD` file just contains the string: `ref: refs/heads/master`.  (The string `refs/heads/master` is in fact the full name of branch-name `master`, though normally you don't need to worry about this: Git hides the `refs/heads/` prefix, just like it hides the `refs/remotes/` prefix when you are using the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.)

When `HEAD` contains a branch name—which, as we just said, is the usual case—the name `HEAD` is mainly just shorthand for writing the current branch name.  So if you're on `master`, `HEAD` is just another way to say `master`.  It's not really all that short, but it has the advantage that it works even if you're on branch [`llanfairpwllgwyngyll`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll).  More importantly, it means that programs like `git log` *don't need to know* what branch you're on—or equivalently, programs like `git status` *can find out* which branch you're on.  In fact, that's precisely *how* `git status` finds out.

#### Quick review

- `git branch` lists your branch names, such as `master`.
- `git remote` lists your remote names, such as `origin`.
- `git branch -r` lists your remote-tracking branches, such as `origin/master`.

## What all this means for the various `git diff` commands

The `git diff` command is itself rather unusual.  Most Git commands treat branch name and revision-list arguments in the way described in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  In `git diff`, though, both the two-dot and three-dot notations `branch1..branch2` and `branch1...branch2` are given new, different meanings.

(Besides this, `git diff` has a whole bunch of sub-modes, which you can invoke with `git diff-index`, `git diff-files`, and `git diff-tree`.  But let's not worry about that here.)

You ran:

> `git diff HEAD...origin master`

There are two extra difficulties here, and I'll completely ignore one of them for a while.  The other problem is that this uses the three-dot notation, with `git diff`'s special interpretation of it, which requires understanding the `git merge-base` command.

Let's simplify this second problem away for a moment by pretending that, instead, you wrote:

```
git diff HEAD..origin master
```

The special `git diff` interpretation of the *two*-dot syntax is a lot simpler: `git diff` pretends you didn't use the two dots at all, and instead just wrote the two names as two separate arguments.  So this particular form means exactly the same thing as:

```
git diff HEAD origin master
```

There's a bit of a problem here, because we've just named *three* things: the special `HEAD` name, a name that looks like (and in fact is) a remote, rather than a branch or remote-tracking branch, and finally a branch name.  The `git diff` command wants *two* things here: it wants two branch names, or at least, two arguments that it can resolve to specific commits.<sup>2</sup>

Of course, `HEAD` works great: it names the current branch, which names the tip-most commit on the branch.  If the current branch is `master` and `master` resolve to commit `24377c8...`, then `HEAD` also resolves to `24377c8...` and Git will use `24377c8...` as the first commit in the diff.

But what about `origin`?  This is where [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) comes in.  It's hard to see at first, but in fact, what happens is that `origin` gets treated as if it reads `origin/HEAD`, and `origin/HEAD` usually<sup>3</sup> maps to `origin/master`, so *usually* this means "whatever commit `git rev-parse origin/master` comes up with".  It definitely always means "whatever commit `git rev-parse origin` comes up with."

Just for concreteness, let's say that your `HEAD` is your `master` which is commit `24377c8...`, and that `origin` is their `master` which is commit `b240a77...`.  Then you could have just typed in this:

```
git diff 24377c8 b240a77 master
```

That is, the two commits `git diff` will compare are these two hashes—we're using these shortened ones here because the full 40 characters is just too much—but what about that extra `master`?

This gets us into the other extra difficulty I mentioned earlier: `git diff` *can* take *more than two* commits, and if it gets three or more commits, it will often<sup>4</sup> produce a "combined diff".  If the word `master` were not a branch name, so that `git rev-parse` complained about it, `git diff` would have treated it as a *path name*, which would restrict the `diff` output to particular paths.  But of course `master` *is* a valid branch name, so it may get parsed as a revision, and may lead to hard-to-describe behavior.  (In Git version 2.8.1, where I tried it out, it acts particularly weird.)

#### Bottom line: don't do that

If you *do* want to use the three-dot form, stick with just one three-dot argument with two branch names.  In this case, Git will use `git merge-base` to find the *merge base* of the two revisions.  (See [Drew Beres' much shorter answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38197190/1256452) for details.<sup>5</sup>)

In the absence of particularly tricky forms, you can simply run `git rev-parse` on the names you are going to feed to `git diff` to see what commits it will use:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD origin
```

This will show you two commit IDs, and those are the two commits that `git diff HEAD origin` or `git diff HEAD..origin` will compare.  When using the three-dot syntax, you can run `git merge-base --all` to see which commit Git will choose to compare to the right-hand-side of the three-dot version.  If that prints just one revision, that's the revision `git diff` will compare to the right-hand side.

(And, remember that all of this behavior is specific to `git diff`: other commands like `git log` treat the two-dot and three-dot syntaxes differently.)

---

<sup>1</sup>You can make remote-tracking branch names that do not start with remote names.  You can also make local branch names that do start with remote names.  Doing either of these is a bad idea as it will confuse humans.  Git will keep them straight—internally, Git uses the `refs/heads` and `refs/remotes/` prefixes to know that they are local and remote-tracking branches—but it's just impossible to work with; don't do it.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, `git diff` wants to resolve the two arguments to two *trees*.  A commit ID always works, though, and branch names resolve to commit IDs, so it probably makes more sense, at least initially, to just concern yourself with finding commits.

<sup>3</sup>When you first `git clone` a URL, Git sets up the remote `origin` to hold the URL, and also finds out—if it can—which branch `HEAD` names in the other Git repository.  It then sets up your remote-tracking name `origin/HEAD` to map to your remote-tracking name for that branch.  Since that branch, in that other Git repository, is usually their `master`, your `origin/HEAD` is usually a symbolic reference to your `origin/master`.

If their Git repository has a different branch checked-out, though, your `origin/HEAD` will point to some other `origin/whatever` name.  (And, in what is probably a bug in Git, `git fetch origin` never actually updates your `origin/HEAD`, even though it probably *should* update it if they change their current branch.)

<sup>4</sup>It gets really bad from here because of the way `git diff` handles the three-dot notation.  However, this depends on your specific version of Git: older versions of Git detected this with literal string tests on the arguments you passed in, and newer ones detect it by looking at flags left behind by the revision-parsing code.  Without building older versions of Git, all I can say is that I am pretty sure that they behave differently from the version I tested.

<sup>5</sup>I started this answer hours ago, was interrupted several times, and found myself unable to explain why some `git diff` commands with three or more branch names and two and three dot syntax produced combined diffs and some produced ordinary diffs, so had to go look at the `builtin/diff.c` source.  It's basically somewhat buggy.  After poking at it for a few hours, I believe I have a fix, although since the Git maintainers have completely ignored [my `git stash` fix](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/234153), I am not hoping for much here.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [git-diff Documentation:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

> **Comparing branches**
>
> ```
> $ git diff topic master    (1)
> $ git diff topic..master   (2)
> $ git diff topic...master  (3)
> ```
>
> 1. Changes between the tips of the topic and the master branches.
> 2. Same as above.
> 3. Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic branch was started off it.

On the triple-period `<commit>...<commit>` git-diff range form specifically:

> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.