# Can I tell Bitbucket to ignore that my maintenance branch is behind?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have two “master” branches in a repo, `develop` for ongoing development and `maint` for updating a mostly frozen old version of the product. The `develop` branch is set as the main branch in the repo setttings. Each time I display the `maint` branch Bitbucket tells me it’s hundreds of commits behind/ahead of `develop`. Is it possible to configure either git or Bitbucket to explain that `maint` will never be merged to `develop` and I am not interested in seeing the differences between them?

This is how the interface looks now:

[image: current screenshot]

And this is how I imagine it could look:

[image: desired interface]

---

(Please note that this is not about tracking or not tracking a remote branch. Both `maint` and `develop` should be on the remote and I want to track both. I just don’t want the Bitbucket web interface showing me meaningless differences between branches that will never get resolved.)

Comment: Can't you change the "main branch" in the repo settings to something else which you're interested in?

Comment: Not really. We do want our main branch to be `develop` (our ongoing master that almost everything compares and eventually merges to), but it makes little sense to compare `maint` to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stop tracking a remote branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git)