# Remove GitHub Branch next to the working directory in cmder Terminal

Tags: windows, git, git-branch, cmder

[See image of cmder terminal with Fixes branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISuM7.jpg)

Next to current directory it says (Fixes --> origin) but when I enter git branch command it does not show any git branches. How do I remove (Fixes --> origin) from showing next to the directory? Why is it showing that branch? This was a branch from a different project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
git branch -avv
```

You will see your local branch Fixes associated to the remote repo named 'origin'

You can [stop tracking the remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/6309) `origin/Fixes` with:

```
git branch --unset-upstream Fixes
```

Then, you won't see `(Fixes --> origin)` anymore, only `(Fixes)`.

The [OP McCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9407778/mccoder) actually finds ([from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330836/remove-github-branch-next-to-the-working-directory-in-cmder-terminal/49331540#comment85666722_49331540)):

> There was a `.git` directory in my `C:\Users\Mel` directory(so one level up).
>
> I removed the directory and the `Fixes` branch finally disappeared!
> I thought it deleted `git` from my entire system but I created a test dir and ran `git init` successfully.

Comment: C:\Users\Mel\Desktop (Fixes -> origin)
λ git branch --unset-upstream Fixes
fatal: Branch 'Fixes' has no upstream information  
========================================================================================================
I typed the above in my terminal. I want to completely remove both Fixes and Origin. My Desktop should not have a git Branch associated with it all.

Comment: @McCoder The command was -avv, not -acc. Check for a .git folder in your current directory or in a parent directory. If you remove it (rename it to .foo, for testing), and Git information should disappear

Comment: There was a .git directory in my C:\Users\Mel directory(so one level up). I removed the directory and the Fixes branch finally disappeared! I thought it deleted git from my entire system but I created a test dir and ran git init successfully. What did you mean by rename it to .foo for testing? What test would I run after renaming the .git directory to .foo?

Comment: @McCoder A .git folder include the full history of a repo. I suggested a rename only if you were interested in that history. If not, deleting it is fine.