# How equalize Visual Studio 2017 local repository with Visual Studio Online Git repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, git-branch

I created a Visual Studio Team Services Git repository.

On my local Visual Studio 2017. I sent the project to this (first commit). All ok.

I created a local branch to modify the project, on VSTS I also created this branch too.

After the code modifications, I sent code to origin/Heineken branch and performed a pull request online.

All set ok, branch Heineken moved to master and after this Heineken was deleted in VSTS.

Now Visual Studio is lost, saying me *Visual Studio Team Foundation git Branch 'Heineken' was not found in the remote repository.*
I don't know what to do to let my VS equated with VSTS.

Some tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reason why VS shows "`Branch 'Heineken' was not found in the remote repository`" is cause the branch `Heineken` was deleted in remote repo but not delete in the local repo.

Steps to equalize the local repo with VSTS git repo as below:

#### 1. Delete local Heineken branch

First, you can checkout to a different branch (such as checkout to `master` branch), then delete the local `Heineken` branch (right click the local `Heineken` branch in VS and delete).

[image]

#### 2. Update remote branch to prune the VSTS git repo deleted branch Heineken

To prune the branch `Heineken` which deleted in remote repo, you can follow any of below options.

- **Pruned by git command line:**

  In the local git repo directory, you can execute the command:

  ```
  git fetch -p
  ```

  So the deleted branch `Heineken` will be moved from `remotes/origin`.
- **Pruned in VS:**

  In Team Explorer -> Settings -> Global Settings -> Set the option Prune remote branches during fetch as True -> update.

  [image]

  Then click fetch (such as in Team Explorer -> sync -> fetch), and the deleted branch `Heineken` won't be shown under `remotes/origin` any more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Git trap, see [How do you stop tracking a remote branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git) for a full answer. The short answer is to open a command prompt and type

```
git checkout Heineken
git branch --unset-upstream
```