# Git how to fix dead origin/master branch?

Tags: git

Given the following notional Git history:

```
A--B--C    (origin/master)  *dead branch*
   \--D--E (working)        *live branch, preferred master*
```

Is there any way to move origin/master to the working live branch, and keep on rolling? I'm very aware of "Why'd you let origin/master go dead? Don't do that", and I will carefully heed that advice in the future. But that's my current reality, and I'm asking for extraction advice.

**Update 2019-08-22:** Here's another very useful post if what you actually want to do is *delete* the remote master branch.  I found [@SlightlyCuban](https://superuser.com/users/223699/slightlycuban)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/748058/how-do-i-delete-origin-master-in-git) to be most helpful here in non-GitHub situations where you have shell access to your remotes.

Also, deleting the local branch that's tracking the remote branch is explained well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478).

Comment: What do you mean by "recover origin/master over to the working live branch"?

Comment: @MinarMahmud good point, "recover" was not a good word choice.  I changed it to "move", and added more explanation for my situation.  Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to force push (because other developers would need to reset their branch), [you can replace `master` by your new branch content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862938/6309):

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout working
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge working
```

Then you can do a simple push

```
git push
```

And other developers, when doing a `git pull`, will get a `master` with a copy of `working` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `git push -f origin working:master` if you want to override remote branch. And, as you've said, this is not a good idea as anyone who works on that branch has to do god knows what, a rebase might not help im not sure