# git - is there a way to untrack several remote merged branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-history

The organization I am working for decided to keep merged branches for history purposes in the repository. The repository has 900+ tracked merged branches and this brings its performance down.
Is there a way to un-track or archive these branches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you stop tracking a remote branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git)

Comment: Kind of. I haven't tried that yet, but it seems that I would have to go into each of the 900+ branches and issue that command, correct?