# GIT unlink local branches and separately replicate them to remote

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm confused in some git operations, this is my scenario:

1. I'm working on a local branch called: "sect11_connect_dbs"
2. in my github remote repo this branch does not exist
3. the output of git status is this:
   [image: git status output]
4. my question is: what commands do I have to use to unlink sect11 branch from sect9 and then replicate it to my remote?

Thanks a lot for your comments

Comment: Push with a new tracking branch? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too/6232535#6232535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
 git push -u origin sect11_connect_dbs
```

That override directly the [unlink part of the local branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/6309):

```sh
git config --unset branch.sect11_connect_dbs.remote
git config --unset branch.sect11_connect_dbs.merge
```

Which can be done also with

```
git branch --unset-upstream sect11_connect_dbs
```

(as noted by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877407/git-unlink-local-branches-and-separately-replicate-them-to-remote/68877619?noredirect=1#comment121728036_68877619))

Comment: Or: `git branch --unset-upstream sect11_connect_dbs`, which does the two `git config`s for you. However, as evolutionxbox noted, the `git push -u` alone will do the job (I think you meant that in your answer too, it's not not clear that the first steps are unnecessary).