# git fetch with path instead of remote

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-remote

I understand the idea of running `git fetch <remote>`, because the remote branches are then available with `git checkout <remote>/<branch>`.

But how does it work if I just run

```
git fetch path/to/other/repo
```

How can I checkout the corresponding branches? Note that the operation runs silently (even with `--verbose`), and that no new branch is created.

**edit**: just to be clear: I perfectly understand how git works with remotes. I'm just curious about this alternate syntax `git fetch path/to/remote`, or `git fetch <url>`. How is it supposed to work? Why does it not create new branches? Why does it run silently even in verbose mode? What is the intended usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best explanation (much better than the docs) is an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch/1071300#1071300) by [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski).

Basically:

```
git fetch <path>
```

just fetches the `HEAD` branch of the remote, and stores it locally into `FETCH_HEAD`.

```
git fetch <path> <branch>
```

fetches the branch in the remote repo and stores it in `FETCH_HEAD`.

More advanced usages are described in Jakub Narębski's answer, but, as he states himself, the best way to fetch is to use named remotes.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's "local" in terms of file system, another repository is a remote repository.

If you want to use it, add it as a remote repository first (even if the url is local):

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

Then, proceed with `git fetch` (and other commands) in the same way as with repository on remote machines.

**EDIT:** 
If you do a simple `git fetch` from a local path, it creates a new pseudo-branch called `FETCH_HEAD`. You can check it out in a new branch for example using:

```
git checkout -b new_branch FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: You did not get the point. I understand how git fetch works with named remote. I *don't* understand how git works when fetching directly from a path (or a url).

Comment: @Olivier, sorry, I've just edited my answer to talk about `FETCH_HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly pass a `refspec` to `git fetch` to get the remote branches. `git help fetch` should help.

Comment: So what is the point of using "git fetch path" without specifying a refspec? And why the "verbose" option does not work??