# git fetch origin creates a new branch

Tags: git

I sync my development code on 2 machines using a git bare repository on a usb drive (followed these steps [git setup for backup & sync between 2 computers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6482960/781695)).

I push my changes to the bare repo on the USB and then fetch & merge on the other machine.

My understanding was that these 2 commands are same, but their output is different. The log shows that the first command creates a new branch.

```
Method 1
git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /usb/backup/code
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master


Method 2
git fetch /usb/backup/code.git
From /usb/backup/code
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because:

```
git fetch origin
```

is the same, when git remote is configured by default, than

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It will tell Git what to fetch and where to store the resulting commit.

But:

```
git fetch path/to/.git
```

means you don't benefit from the default refspec setting `origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, which means you are doing:

```
git fetch path/to/.git HEAD:
```

(you fetch the remote `HEAD` without specifying where to put it).
The resulting commit [is stored in `FETCH_HEAD` ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036817/in-git-how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-repositorys-remote-branches).

See "[Having a hard time understanding `git-fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch)" for more.
(and "[`git fetch` with path instead of remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829426/git-fetch-with-path-instead-of-remote)")