# What is a tracking branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

Can someone explain a "tracking branch" as it applies to git?

Here's the definition from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches):

> A 'tracking branch' in Git is a local
>   branch that is connected to a remote
>   branch. When you push and pull on that
>   branch, it automatically pushes and
>   pulls to the remote branch that it is
>   connected with.
>
> Use this if you always pull from the
>   same upstream branch into the new
>   branch, and if you don't want to use
>   "git pull" explicitly.

Unfortunately, being new to git and coming from SVN, that definition makes absolutely no sense to me.

I'm reading through "[The Pragmatic Guide to Git](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/pg_git/pragmatic-guide-to-git)" (great book, by the way), and they seem to suggest that tracking branches are a good thing and that after creating your first remote (origin, in this case), you should set up your master branch to be a tracking branch, but it unfortunately doesn't cover *why a tracking branch is a good thing* or *what benefits you get by setting up your master branch to be a tracking branch of your origin repository*.

Can someone please enlighten me (in English)?

Comment: One terminology note: the word *track*, in Git, is very badly overloaded. Some files are *tracked* and some are *untracked;* some branch names are called *remote-tracking branches;* and you can use the `--track` option to create a (local) branch that has one of these remote-tracking branches set as its *upstream*. The terminology has evolved somewhat between 2006 and 2019, so different people *may* sometimes mean something different by each of these words.

Comment: I personally recommend using the phrase *remote-tracking names* in place of *remote-tracking branches*, in part because the word *branch* is also rather overloaded. The remote-tracking names are the ones that look like `origin/master`: they're in your repository, but they are your Git's way of remembering *branch names* as seen in some *other* Git repository over at `origin`. If you then use the word *upstream*, which is the more modern term, to say that your `master` has `origin/master` set as its *upstream*, you can avoid all this terminology confusion.

Comment: @torek, the term  “remote-tracking branch” can’t be replaced by phrase remote-tracking names, as tracking branches have physical state, that can be be different from both local and remote branches

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: [A rose, by any other name ...](https://literarydevices.net/a-rose-by-any-other-name/) If you're concerned with the storage of a hash ID, you should realize that in Git, hash IDs are stored under *names*. Not just *branch* names, but *tag* names, `refs/stash`, bisect names, and other names: all of these store a hash ID.

Comment: It might be helpfull to know that with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a git config [`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time/72401899#72401899) that can set this for you. That way you do not need to worry about it as much.

Comment: @torek an alternative by-the-book name would be "remote tracking _pointers_".

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The [ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book) has [a very good explanation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches):

**Tracking Branches**

Checking out a local branch from a remote branch automatically creates what is called a tracking branch. Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch. If you’re on a tracking branch and type `git push`, Git automatically knows which server and branch to push to. Also, running `git pull` while on one of these branches fetches all the remote references and then automatically merges in the corresponding remote branch.

When you clone a repository, it generally automatically creates a master branch that tracks origin/master. That’s why `git push` and `git pull` work out of the box with no other arguments. However, you can set up other tracking branches if you wish — ones that don’t track branches on origin and don’t track the master branch. The simple case is the example you just saw, running `git checkout -b [branch] [remotename]/[branch]`. If you have Git version 1.6.2 or later, you can also use the `--track` shorthand:

```
$ git checkout --track origin/serverfix
Branch serverfix set up to track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/serverfix.
Switched to a new branch "serverfix"
```

To set up a local branch with a different name than the remote branch, you can easily use the first version with a different local branch name:

```
$ git checkout -b sf origin/serverfix
Branch sf set up to track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/serverfix.
Switched to a new branch "sf"
```

Now, your local branch `sf` will automatically push to and pull from `origin/serverfix`.

**BONUS: extra `git status` info**

With a tracking branch, `git status` will tell you how far behind your tracking branch you are - useful to remind you that you haven't pushed your changes yet! It looks like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

or

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 3 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Comment: @JohnO, might want to take that up with the Pro Git guy. The whole book is a result of massive editing collaboration IIRC.

Comment: @ JohnO, according to : https://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/git-4.shtml --track is on by default and so is not necessary.

Comment: Just an FYI , as I see many people make the same mistake with "git status" -  It doesnt check if your local master/any branch for that matter ,is in sync with the remote branch, so when git status says "up to date..." . dont get confused and believe that your branch is in sync with the remote, as git status doesnt do any network calls, it just checks the difference between your current repo state and the state of the repo when it got cloned/updated in local.
To check for syncs/updates in remote use "git fetch".

Comment: what if I want to do a 1 time pull from origin/dev into abc local branch? I don't want to push and pull dynamically from origin/dev? In that case, I won't track the branch, just do a pull, right?

Answer (score 54):

[The Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) [mentions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches):

> Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch

Not exactly. The SO question "[Having a hard time understanding `git-fetch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch)" includes:

> There's no such concept of *local tracking* branches, only *remote tracking* branches.
> So **`origin/master`** is a remote tracking branch for **`master`** in the **`origin`** repo.

---

Note that [Git 2.37 (Q3 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309) allows you to aumtomatically setup that remote tracking branch, with:

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

---

But actually, once you establish an [upstream branch relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) between:

- a local branch like `master`
- and a remote tracking branch like `origin/master`

You can list them with `git branch -avv`.

Then you can consider `master` as a **local tracking branch**: It tracks the **remote tracking branch** `origin/master` which, in turn, tracks the master branch of the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) `origin`.

[image]

In other words: "remote" in "remote tracking branch" means a *local* copy (tracking) of the remote branch, to remember what was last fetched.
As [Michael Freidgeim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52277/michael-freidgeim) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/what-is-a-tracking-branch/4697054#comment117599685_4697054):

> The term "remote tracking branches" is confusing.
>
> The more precise word be:
>
> > "**locally located remote-tracking branch**".
>
> Otherwise someone could interpret that “remote tracking branch” is located on the origin server.

Comment: Image clarification: My Computer is 2 commits ahead of origin. That's where those two commits off of master come from. Image: http://progit.org/book/ch3-5.html

Comment: Am I interpreting correctly: If I locally have remotes set for origin and upstream , then my local master branch will track origin directly, and upstream indirectly? eg: when I `git status` I'll receive a commit tracking message with respect both origin and upstream repos?  (Settup: I cloned someone's repo locally, pushed my clone to a new repo on my GitHub account, and locally set origin and upstream remotes to my github repo and the cloned cloned repo respectively).

Comment: @SherylHohman No: a local branch won't track anything "directly" or "indirectly". It will track the remote tracking branch you will assign to it. In case of a fork, the best practice is to track upstream (the original repo) for common branches (like master), and track origin (your remote fork) for new branches (your PR or feature branches): see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21847690/6309

Comment: @VonC - The statement "There's no such concept of local tracking branches, only remote tracking branches." is interesting b/c there's such conflicting terminology around branches. This often referenced link https://web.archive.org/web/20130419172453/http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches distinguishes between "tracking branches" & "remote tracking branches". They call origin/master a "remote tracking branch" - I agree - but then they call "master" a "tracking branch" too. What is master tracking? Are they wrong or is it a terminology problem?

Comment: @Howiecamp what they call a "tracking branch called master" is simply a local branch master with an associated remote tracking branch origin/master, here to memorized the last SHA1 fetched from origin regarding its remote master branch. So it is a "shortcut" for designating "a local branch with an upstream branch"

Comment: "It tracks the remote tracking branch origin/master" what does tracking mean? That any time I do `git pull origin` or `git fetch origin` without anything after it then it will pull down whatever that it's in `origin/master` into local `master`? and if it wasn't being tracked then that command won't do that for me. I'd have to do `git pull origin master` for it to work? (**EDITED**)

Comment: "tracking" (for `master` relative to `origin/master`) is not the best term: "is associated to" would be better. "`origin/master`" is a (remote) tracking branch, as it "tracks" (ie.: records the last known fetch commit of) a remote branch. But `master` is just a branch you can "associate" to any remote tracking branch you want, in order to help Git answer the question, on a `git push`, of "what remote branch do you want me to push your stuff (commits from `master`)?" Or, on a `git pull`, "what local branch do you want me to merge the fetched commits of the remote branch?"

Comment: The term  “remote tracking branches” is confusing. The more precise word be “ locally located remote-tracking branch”. Otherwise someone could interprete that “remote tracking branch” is located on the origin server.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim I agree. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 12):

This was how I added a tracking branch so I can pull from it into my new branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/Development new-branch
```

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**  Remember, all git **branches** are themselves used for **tracking** the history of a set of files.  Therefore, **isn't every branch actually a "tracking branch"**, because that's what these branches are used for: to track the history of files over time?

**Thus we should probably be calling normal git "branches", "tracking-branches", but we don't.  Instead we shorten their name to just "branches".**

---

So that's partly why the term "tracking-branches" is so terribly confusing: to the uninitiated it can easily mean 2 different things.

**In git the term "Tracking-branch" is a short name for the more complete term: "Remote-tracking-branch"**.

It's probably better at first if you substitute the more formal terms until you get more comfortable with these concepts.

---

Let's rephrase your question to this:

### **What is a "*Remote*-tracking-branch?"**

The key word here is 'Remote', so skip down to where you get confused and I'll describe what a Remote Tracking branch is and how it's used.

---

To better understand **git terminology**, including *branches* and *tracking*, which can initially be very confusing, I think it's easiest if you first get crystal clear on **what git is** and the basic structure of **how it works**.  Without a solid understand like this I promise you'll get lost in the many details, as git has lots of complexity; (translation: lots of people use it for very important things).

The following is an introduction/overview, but you might find [this excellent article](https://github.blog/2020-12-17-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs/) also informative.

---

**WHAT GIT IS, AND WHAT IT'S FOR**

**A git repository is like a family photo album:**  It holds historical snapshots showing how things were in past times.  A "snapshot" being a recording of something, at a given moment in time.

A git repository is not limited to holding human family photos.  It, rather can be **used to record and organize *anything that is evolving or changing over time***.

The basic idea is to create a book so we can easily look backwards in time,

- **to compare** past times, with now, or other moments in time, and
- **to re-create** the past.

---

*When you get mired down in the complexity and terminology, try to remember that **a git repository** is first and foremost, **a repository of snapshots**, and just like a photo album, it's used to both store and organize these snapshots.*

---

**SNAPSHOTS AND TRACKING**

> **tracked**  - to follow a person or animal by looking for proof that they have been somewhere ([dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tracked))

In git, "**your project**" refers to a directory tree of files (one or more, possibly organized into a tree structure using sub-directories), which you wish to keep a history of.

Git, via a 3 step process, records a "**snapshot**" of your project's directory tree at a given moment in time.

Each git snapshot of your project, is then organized by "**links**" pointing to previous snapshots of your project.

One by one, link-by-link, we can look backwards in time to find any previous snapshot of you, or your heritage.

**For example**, we can start with today's most recent snapshot of you, and then using a link, seek backwards in time, for a photo of you taken perhaps yesterday or last week, or when you were a baby, or even who your mother was, etc.

This is refereed to as "**tracking**;  in this example it is tracking your life, or seeing where you have left a footprint, and where you have come from.

---

**COMMITS**

**A commit** is similar to one page in your photo album with a single snapshot, in that its not just the snapshot contained there, but also has the associated meta information about that snapshot.  It includes:

- an address or fixed place where we can find this commit, similar to its page number,
- one snapshot of your project (of your file directory tree) at a given moment in time,
- a caption or comment saying what the snapshot is of, or for,
- the date and time of that snapshot,
- who took the snapshot, and finally,
- one, *or more*, **links** backwards in time to previous, related snapshots like to yesterday's snapshot, or to our parent or parents.  In other words "links" are similar to pointers to the page numbers of other, older photos of myself, or when I am born to my immediate parents.

**A commit is the most important part of a well organized photo album.**

---

**THE FAMILY TREE OVER TIME, WITH BRANCHES AND MERGES**

***Disambiguation:**  "Tree" here refers not to a file directory tree, as used above, but rather to a family tree of related parent and child commits over time.*

The git family tree structure is modeled on our own, human family trees.

In what follows to help understand links in a simple way, I'll refer to:

- a **parent-commit** as simply a "**parent**", and
- a **child-commit** as simply a "**child**" or "children" if plural.

You should understand this instinctively, as it is based on the tree of life:

- A parent *might* have one or more children pointing back in time at them, and
- children always have one *or more* parents they point to.

Thus all commits except brand new commits, (you could say "juvenile commits"), have one or more children pointing back at them.

- With no children are pointing to a parent, then this commit is only a "**growing tip**", or where the next child will be born from.
- With just one child pointing at a parent, this is just a simple, single parent <-- child relationship.

**Line diagram of a simple, single parent chain linking backwards in time:**

```
(older) ... <--link1-- Commit1 <--link2-- Commit2 <--link3-- Commit3 (newest)
```

---

BRANCHES

> **branch** - A "branch" is an active line of development. The most recent commit on a branch is referred to as the tip of that branch.
> The tip of the branch is referenced by a branch head, which moves
> forward as additional development is done on the branch. A single Git
> repository can *track* an arbitrary number of branches, but your
> working tree is associated with just one of them (the "current" or
> "checked out" branch), and HEAD points to that branch.  ([gitglossary](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/gitglossary.7.html))

A git branch also refers to two things:

- a name given to a growing tip, (an identifier), and
- the actual branch in the graph of links between commits.

**More than one child pointing --at a--> parent**, is what git calls "**branching**".

NOTE:  In reality any child, of any parent, weather first, second, or third, etc., can be seen as their own little branch, with their own growing tip.  So a branch is not necessarily a long thing with many nodes, rather it is a little thing, created with just one or more commits from a given parent.

The first child of a parent might be said to be part of that same branch, whereas the successive children of that parent are what are normally called "**branches**".

In actuality, all children (not just the first) branch from it's parent, or you could say **link**, but I would argue that each **link** is actually the core part of **a branch**.

**Formally, a git "branch" is just a name**, like 'foo' for example, given to a specific growing tip of a family hierarchy.  It's one type of what they call a "**ref**".  (Tags and remotes which I'll explain later are also refs.)

> **ref** - A name that begins with refs/ (e.g.  refs/heads/master) that points to an object name or another ref (the latter is called a
> symbolic ref). For convenience, a ref can sometimes be abbreviated
> when used as an argument to a Git command; see gitrevisions(7) for
> details. Refs are stored in the repository.
>
> The ref namespace is hierarchical. Different subhierarchies are used
> for different purposes (e.g. the refs/heads/ hierarchy is used to
> represent local branches). There are a few special-purpose refs that
> do not begin with refs/. The most notable example is HEAD.  ([gitglossary](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/gitglossary.7.html))

(You should take a look at the file tree inside your `.git` directory.  It's where the structure of git is saved.)

So for example, if your name is Tom, then commits linked together that only include snapshots of you, might be the branch we name "Tom".

So while you might think of a tree branch as all of it's wood, in git a branch is just a name given to it's growing tips, not to the whole stick of wood leading up to it.

The special growing tip and it's branch which an arborist (a guy who prunes fruit trees) would call the "central leader" is what git calls "**master**".

The master branch always exists.

**Line diagram of: Commit1 with 2 children** (or what we call a git "**branch**"):

```
                parent      children

                        +-- Commit <-- Commit <-- Commit (Branch named 'Tom')
                       /
                      v
(older) ... <-- Commit1 <-- Commit                       (Branch named 'master')
```

Remember, a link *only* points from child to parent.
There is no link pointing the other way, i.e. from old to new, that is from parent to child.

So a parent-commit has no direct way to list it's children-commits, or in other words, what was derived from it.

---

MERGING

**Children have one *or more* parents.**

- With just one parent this is just a simple parent <-- child commit.
- With more than one parent this is what git calls "**merging**".
  Each child can point back to more than one parent at the same time, just as in having both a mother AND father, not just a mother.

**Line diagram of:  Commit2 with 2 parents** (or what we call a git "**merge**", i.e. Procreation from multiple parents):

```
                parents     child

           ... <-- Commit
                        v
                         \
(older) ... <-- Commit1 <-- Commit2
```

---

**REMOTE**

This word is also used to mean 2 different things:

- a remote repository, and
- the local alias name for a remote repository, i.e. a name which points using a URL to a remote repository.

> **remote repository** - A repository which is used to track the same project but resides somewhere else. To communicate with remotes, see
> fetch or push.  ([gitglossary](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/gitglossary.7.html))

(The remote repository can even be another git repository on our own computer.)
Actually there are two URLS for each remote name, one for pushing (i.e. uploading commits) and one for pulling (i.e. downloading commits) from that remote git repository.

A "**remote**" is a *name* (an identifier) which has an associated URL which points to a remote git repository.  (It's been described as an alias for a URL, although it's more than that.)

You can setup multiple remotes if you want to pull or push to multiple remote repositories.

Though often you have just one, and it's default name is "origin" (meaning the upstream origin from where you cloned).

> **origin** - The default *upstream* repository. Most projects have at least one upstream project which they track. By default origin is used
> for that purpose. New upstream updates will be fetched into
> *remote-tracking branches* named origin/name-of-upstream-branch, which you can see using git branch -r.  ([gitglossary](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/gitglossary.7.html))

Origin represents where you cloned the repository from.
That remote repository is called the "upstream" repository, and your cloned repository is called the "downstream" repository.

> **upstream** - In software development, upstream refers to a direction toward the original authors or maintainers of software that is distributed as source code [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_(software_development))

> **upstream branch** - The default branch that is merged into the branch in question (or the branch in question is rebased onto).
> It is configured via branch..remote and branch..merge. If the upstream branch of A is origin/B sometimes we say "A is tracking origin/B".  ([gitglossary](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/gitglossary.7.html))

This is because most of the water generally flows down to you.
From time to time you might push some software back up to the upstream repository, so it can then flow down to all who have cloned it.

**REMOTE TRACKING BRANCH**

A remote-tracking-branch is first, just a branch name, like any other branch name.

It points at a local growing tip, i.e. a recent commit in *your* local git repository.

But note that it effectively also points to the same commit in the remote repository that you cloned the commit from.

> **remote-tracking branch** - A ref that is used to follow changes from another repository. It typically looks like refs/remotes/foo/bar
> (indicating that it tracks a branch named bar in a remote named foo),
> and matches the right-hand-side of a configured fetch refspec. A remote-tracking branch should not contain direct modifications or have
> local commits made to it.  ([gitglossary](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/gitglossary.7.html))

Say the remote you cloned just has 2 commits, like this: `parent4 <== child-of-4`, and you clone it and now your local git repository has the same exact two commits: `parent4 <== child-of-4`.
Your remote tracking branch named **origin** now points to `child-of-4`.

Now say that a commit is added to the remote, so it looks like this:  `parent4 <== child-of-4 <== new-baby`.  To update your local, downstream repository you'll need to fetch new-baby, and add it to your local git repository.  Now your local remote-tracking-branch points to new-baby.  You get the idea, the concept of a remote-tracking-branch is simply to keep track of what had previously been the tip of a remote branch that you care about.

---

TRACKING IN ACTION

First we begin tracking a file with git.

[image]

Here are the basic commands involved with file tracking:

```
$ mkdir mydir &&  cd mydir &&  git init         # create a new git repository

$ git branch                                    # this initially reports no branches
                                                #  (IMHO this is a bug!)

$ git status -bs   # -b = branch; -s = short    # master branch is empty
## No commits yet on master

# ...
$ touch foo                                     # create a new file

$ vim foo                                       # modify it (OPTIONAL)


$ git add         foo; commit -m 'your description'  # start tracking foo 
$ git rm  --index foo; commit -m 'your description'  # stop  tracking foo 
$ git rm          foo; commit -m 'your description'  # stop  tracking foo 
                                                     #   & also delete foo
```

REMOTE TRACKING IN ACTION

```
$ git pull    # Essentially does:  get fetch; git merge    # to update our clone
```

There is much more to learn about fetch, merge, etc, but this should get you off in the right direction I hope.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned how to see all tracking branches that are already setup, thus here is the command, consider this a partial answer, read the rest to understand what a tracking branch is:

git branch -vv

to see all tracking branches that are set up.

My short answer for you is: a tracking branch, is like a normal branch but with a "link" to some remote repository's branch, if the remote branch changes, your local branch will be notify when you do

git status

Answer (score 1):

tracking branch is a way to save us some typing. It also give use some extra details when using `git status` and `git branch -v`.

Now let me explain what I mean by "save us some typing".

If we track a branch, we do not have to always type `git push origin <branch-name>` or `git pull origin <branch-name>` or `git fetch origin <branch-name>` or `git merge origin <branch-name>`. ***given we named our remote `origin`***, we can just use `git push`, `git pull`, `git fetch`,`git merge`, respectively. If we do not name our remove `origin`, we can use `git push <remote-name>`, `git pull <remote-name>`, `git fetch <remote-name>`,`git merge <remote-name>`, respectively.

Executing the default invocation of `git pull` will is equivalent to `git fetch origin HEAD` and `git merge HEAD` where `HEAD` is ref pointing to the current branch.

The `git push` command sends all of the commits on your current branch to the central repository. So, the command looks like `git push origin <current-branch>`

If we are on a branch which we are tracking, the mere phrase `git merge` is taken to mean `git merge origin/<current-branch>`.

We track a branch when we:

1. clone a repository using `git clone`
2. use `git push -u origin <branch-name>`. This `-u` make it a tracking branch.
3. use `git branch -u origin/<branch-name> <branch-name>`
4. use `--track` while checkout. Ex. `git checkout --track origin/<branch-name>`