# git push and pull branches

Tags: git, branch

This question has been asked a few times but i haven't found my specific use case:
I do have a nas which has gitosis and serves as a git master. I have a laptop and a desktop, on the laptop I do have a branch sandbox which I want to share via the nas on to the desktop.
I tried git

```
git push sandbox : sandbox (: sandbox being redundant)
```

which failed. Checking out sandbox and doing

```
git push origin HEAD
```

reports:

```
* [new branch]      HEAD -> sandbox
```

Now on the desktop I do:

```
git remote show origin
```

and I see the new branch:

```
Remote branches:
master tracked
sandbox new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
```

That's promising so now I want to pull the remote branch sandbox into my workspace on the desktop with:

```
git fetch origin sandbox (in the master branch)
```

it logs:

```
 * branch            sandbox      -> FETCH_HEAD
```

but branch sandbox is not created when I show the branches. Is there something trivial i'm missing? I also tried pulling but that also does not work as expected. regards,
Jeroen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sandbox should be listed if you do a:

```
git branch --all
```

You need to checkout said remote branch to [track it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/git-what-is-a-tracking-branch)

```
git checkout --track origin/sandbox
```

Then a simple `git branch` would show that branch.