# Cloning git repository inside another git repository

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo from github (for example 'hello world') the I cloned another repo inside the hello world like this :

```
$ git clone ********hello_world
$cd ~/hello_world
~/hello_world $ git clone  ***************another_repo
```

What's the relationship between them?
What if I delete the .git of the hello world?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Clone Into Another Existing Git Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360342/git-clone-into-another-existing-git-repo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those repositories do not influence each other unless you set inner repository as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of the outer repository. If submodule is not set, the outer repository will recognize inner repository as a separate entity (because it contains separate .git directory).