# git repo inside git repo without submodules

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to have isolated git repositories inside another repositories.
My idea is to have a (base)repo containing the tools and client documentation of my team and the projects being an optional part of the directory structure: |

```
/home
  /me
    /myTeam(baseGit)
      /tools
      /clientDocumentation
      /projects
        /project1(git)
        /project1(git)
```

In the example above, I want to have bash files containing the commands needed to download the "porjectX repo" twhen needed.
in this case we can simply start a new worker with the base repo containing all the start info and tooling, and have him/her download the projects when needed.

How can I create this structure without the base Git repository assuming the projects as submodules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I arrange repositories into folders on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852982/can-i-arrange-repositories-into-folders-on-github)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Clone Into Another Existing Git Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360342/git-clone-into-another-existing-git-repo)