# Deleting a remote branch

Tags: git, branch

When I perform `branch -a`:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/hello
 remotes/origin/master
```

And then I remove the branch:

```
$ git branch -r -D origin/hello
Deleted remote branch origin/hello (was c0cbfd0).
```

Now I see:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/master
```

The branch "hello" has been removed.
But when I fetch:

```
$ git fetch
From localhost:project
 * [new hello]      hello     -> origin/hello

$ git branch -a
* master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/hello
 remotes/origin/master
```

I'm so confused.
I think it has been removed, but it is still there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove it from the remote with the following command:

```
git push origin --delete hello
```

When you are running `git branch -rd origin/hello` you are deleting your local branch only. The code above removes it from the origin repo.

Answer (score 3):

To [delete a remote branch](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html), use

```
git push origin :remotebranch
```

Everything else operates on the local repository only.
In more recent versions of git, you can also

```
git push origin --delete remotebranch
```

As per the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html), `--delete` means the same "as prefixing all refs with a colon".

If you are wondering about meaning of the `:`, it follows the standard syntax for `push`. Usually, you would write

```
git push origin localbranch:remotebranch
```

but here, you replace `localbranch` with "nothing", effectively deleting the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

Note that git branch only allows for deleting *local* references.

```
 git branch -r -D origin/hello
```

That only delete the local pointer to a **[remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/git-what-is-a-tracking-branch/4697054#4697054)**, but that has no influence on the remote repo content itself.
Only the `git push origin :hello`, as mentioned in the other answers, would do that.

Plus, that doesn't change the config `branch.hello.fetch`: it still references origin/hello, which is why the next fetch will re-create the remote tracking branch in your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin --delete somebranch
```

is the way you delete a remote branch. If you are still on an old version of Git, you may need to use the old syntax:

```
git push origin :somebranch
```

which translates to "push nothing into somebranch on the remote pointed to by origin". The command is of the form "git push (which remote repo) (what local reference):(which remote reference). Omitting (what reference) is interpreted as "put nothing" into (which remote reference), effectively deleting it. The newer syntax is much more intuitive.