# Pull all branches from origin

Tags: git

I can say this:

```
git push --all origin
```

and it will push **all branches** to origin. But if I do this:

```
git pull --all origin
```

then it doesn't **pull** all the branches **from** origin, it just returns an error:

```
fatal: fetch --all does not take a repository argument
```

Ok, I do this:

```
git pull --all
```

buy yet it says:

```
You asked to pull from the remote '--all', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

So how do I pull all the branches from origin (like I **push** all branches **to** origin by `git push --all origin`)?

Comment: What if you run `git pull origin`? Or better `git fetch origin`

Comment: `git fetch` already does this.

Comment: @meagar, but fetch is not the same as pull.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp So?

Comment: @meagar, so it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp How is it not what you're looking for? It downloads all the remote branches. It's the closest thing you're going to get to "pulling" all remote branches; are you hung up on the word "pull"?

Comment: I think that he wants to pull the commits into the corresponding tracking local branches. Fetch is not enough for it, as it only fetches new commits regarding the remote origin, but doesn't updates the tracking branches references.

Answer (score 16):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152011/1256452) contains all items you need to make various setups work, but could use a bit of background explanation for those somewhat new to git.

In what I think is a very unfortunate bit of naming, git has `fetch`, `push`, and `pull`.  It *sounds like* `pull` is the opposite-direction equivalent of `push`, but it's not!  The closest thing `push` has to an opposite is actually `fetch` (and even then they're not entirely symmetric).

To properly understand all this, you need to know that in git, branch names are merely *labels* for specific commits, with one very special property.  A "regular" or "local" branch name—usually just called "a branch"—like `master` has the special property that, when you check it out by branch name and then make new commits in your repository, that branch name *automatically moves forward* to include your new commits.  (And each new commit points back to its "parent" older commit—or, for merges, to all its parents.)

Git also provides "remote branches", which (in git tradition) have a somewhat misleading name since they also live in *your* repository, not in some other "remote" repository.  These are prefixed with the name of the remote, e.g., `origin`, so you have `origin/master` as a "remote branch".  Again, these are just labels for commits.  Unlilke your local branches, they don't move when you make commits—but they *do* move.  They move when you use `git fetch`.

When you run `git fetch`, your git contacts some remote (`origin`) and asks it what branches<sup>1</sup> it has, and what those labels point to.  You can see this by running `git ls-remote`:

```
$ git ls-remote
From ssh://[redacted]
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f    HEAD
222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83    refs/heads/branch
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f    refs/heads/master
d41117433d7b4431a188c0eddec878646bf399c3    refs/tags/tag-foo
```

**A normal `fetch` brings over *all* the branches, writing them into your repository under different names.**  In this case, `master` becomes `origin/master` and `branch` becomes `origin/branch`.<sup>2</sup>

To bring over a branch-label, it also brings over the commit itself (such as `222c4dd...` above), plus any other underlying objects needed to make the commit complete.  (This includes any development history that they have, that you don't already have.)  Then the new, remote-adjusted branch name (`origin/branch`) is set to point directly to that commit (`222c4dd...`).

Thus, as already noted, `git fetch` brings over all branches, just as `git push --all` pushes all branches.  What `fetch` does *not* do is *merge* any of those updates into your own local branches.  This is also where `fetch` and `push` stop being mirror-images of each other: **when you `push` a branch to a remote, *there is no automatic renaming*.**<sup>3</sup>

Again, when we bring over their `master`, it becomes `origin/master`.  None of our branches are named `origin/whatever`, so this can't possibly break *our* branches.  But when we push our `master` to them, we just tell them to set it up as *their* `master`.  We don't say: "push our `master` to your `alexander/master`".<sup>4</sup>  This is why, before we push, we usually have to either merge or rebase our `master` with theirs, so that when we tell them "hey, set your `master` to commit `af7c315`", we make sure that this new commit-ID incorporates all the history they have, so that they don't lose any.

This is where `git pull` comes in.  To update their `master`, we need to first bring over their `master`, with `git fetch`, which will rename it `origin/master` in our local copy.  Then, once we're in sync with them, we merge-or-rebase our `master` and our `origin/master` (which is now in sync with their `master`).  Finally, when that's done and is good, we can push our new `master`—it's now based on / merged with our `origin/master` that matches their `master`—to their `master`.  As long as all this happens fast enough, this all works.  (If it's not fast enough—if someone else beats us to the `push`—then we have to fetch again, merge-or-rebase again, and try the `push` again, repeating until we win the race against everyone else also trying to `push`.)

The `git pull` script simply automates the fetch-and-merge/rebase part.  But it does this with *only one branch*: whatever branch we have checked out right now.  This is because, in git, the `merge` and `rebase` commands only change one branch: `merge` merges into the current branch, and `rebase` generally rebases the current branch.  (If you tell `git rebase` to rebase some other branch, it does that by first checking it out.)

If you want to merge-or-rebase multiple branches, you have to check each one out, one at a time.  (It's slightly easier with `rebase` since `git rebase origin/master master` starts by doing `git checkout master`—so it's built in to the command—but you're still doing a `git checkout`.)  Fortunately `git fetch origin` will update all the remote-branches at once, so you need only one `git fetch`.

Git generally assumes that unless you plan to *change* something in a branch, or freeze it at a particular commit, you don't check out your own version of it.  That is, you don't do:

```
$ git checkout --track feature origin/feature
```

unless you plan to do something with it.  So unless you're already on branch `feature`, there's no call to rebase-or-merge it.

Because `git clone` does an initial checkout, usually of `master`, while people often work on feature branches instead, it's pretty common to wind up with one branch you'll work on (`feature`) and one local branch you don't need (`master`).  But there's nothing wrong with just leaving that branch to get further and further behind `origin/master` until you do need it; or you can even just delete it, once you've done a `git checkout` of some other branch:

```
$ git checkout branch       # newer gits do --track automatically
Branch branch set up to track remote branch branch from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'branch'
$ git branch -d master
warning: deleting branch 'master' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/master', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch master (was d1574b8).
$
```

(the warning is annoying but harmless).

---

<sup>1</sup>The `fetch` can also see tags and other refs, and you can instruct it to bring more stuff over.  The example above shows one tag, plus `HEAD`.  Adding `--tags`, or changing the `fetch =` line, allows you to bring the tags over.  The `HEAD` reference is extra-special, and there's a long-standing subtle bug in the way git treats `HEAD` for clone operations, which is usually not important and requires a change in the protocols to fix, so no one has fixed it.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, `refs/heads/*` maps to `refs/remotes/origin/*` with the `*` part being copied across.  So if the remote has a `refs/heads/this/that`, you get `refs/remotes/origin/this/that`.  This is what the `fetch =` line under the `remote` definition in your `.git/config` file is about: it tells `fetch` how to re-map remote references.  This is also why I say a "normal" fetch: you can configure it, or run it with options, to make it act differently.

People new to git might wonder why it does this renaming.  Well, suppose you start by grabbing their `master` and making a new local `master` branch so that you can change things.  Then you change some things, and use `git add` and `git commit` to create at least one new commit.  Meanwhile they (whoever "they" are) have *also* changed things and made new commits.  You want to see what they did, so you `git fetch` their new stuff.  If that overwrote your `master`, what would happen to *your* work?  Fortunately git brings over their new stuff under a different name: `origin/master`.  Your `master` remains unchanged, tracking your new commits.

<sup>3</sup>At least, not by default.  As with most things git, you can change this behavior, with command line flags and configuration entries.

<sup>4</sup>Actually, as already noted in footnote 3, we *can* do exactly that, and in some setups, you might even *want* to.  But that's not generally how people use git with sharing repositories.

Comment: +1. Note that the "remote branches" are actually "remote tracking branches", ie branches that tracks locally their counterpart in the upstream repo.

Comment: Thanks. And if I know that there is a remote branch called "some_branch1" and there is no local branch which tracks it, what's the proper way to "copy" (fetch, pull?) "some_branch1" from remote to local?

Comment: Plain old `git fetch` will create-or-update `origin/some_branch1`, and in the process, bring over any needed underlying git objects.  If you want to view what's in it, `git log origin/some_branch1` will show you.  By default, there are reflogs for remote branches as well, so you can see what happened since the last update: `git log origin/some_branch1@{1}..origin/some_branch1`.

Comment: I had a local branch develop and there were 2 branches on origin. When I called git fetch origin, it updated only my local develop branch. Why didn't it update or create the master? Should I create and checkout to master first and then call git fetch to get origin/master?

Comment: Re-read the answer above, keeping in mind that `git fetch origin` does not update *any* local branches.  It updates (your copies of) the *remote-tracking branches*, such as `origin/some_branch1` and `origin/master`.  You must distinguish between your personal branches, and the "remote branches", because git does.

Answer (score 5):

`git pull` with first `git fetch` everything, meaning the `origin` namespace will include all [(remote tracking) branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21499072/6309) from `origin` (see [fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915046/6309)).

But it will merge only `origin/currentBranch` to `currentBranch`.

It won't create the other branches.

If it were to creates *all* the branches from `origin`, your git branch would be "polluted" by the potentially many branches of the upstream repo.
Generally, you only want as local branches the one you will be working on.

If you want to track all branches from remote, you can refer to [this one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309) from the question "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379081/6309)".

Comment: `If you want to track all branches from remote, you can refer to this one-liner from the question` - that's a script, isn't there a standard git's command for that? There is one for push (git push --all origin), but doesn't there exist the same one for pull?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp no it doesn't exist, because in 99% of the cases, nobody wants to create as local branches *all* the remote branches: that would pollute your list of branches with tons of branches you don't need. They are all here after a fetch in the remote namespace, but you don't need them as local branch.