# What does 'git fetch -p' (or --prune) mean

Tags: git

I had run this command with misunderstandings while I was deleting my one local branch,

```
git branch -D branch-name

git fetch -p
```

but I have seen their is a list of branch names that are showing to be deleted.

I was afraid to see the list of deleted branches list, and thinking might be I had executed wrong command, and accidentally deleted all the branches!!

What does mean of this command (`git fetch -p`). Any idea?

Comment: Note: `git fetch --prune` got a bit more precise: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21074116/6309)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

When you fetch a remote repository, say “origin”, you will get *remote branches* for each branch that exists on that remote repository. Those branches are locally stored as `<remote>/<branch>`.

So assume origin has branches `master`, `featureX` and `featureY`. Then after fetching the following “remote branches” exist in your local repository: `origin/master`, `origin/featureX` and `origin/featureY`.

Now, imagine someone else merges `featureX` into master and removes the feature branch from the remote repository. Then origin only has two branches `master` and `featureY`.

However, when you fetch, the three remote branches will all still exist, including the one that was deleted in the remote repository. This is to prevent you from accidentally losing the branch (imagine someone accidentally removed the branch from the remote, then everyone who fetched from it would also lose it, making it hard to restore it).

Instead, you will need to tell the fetch command to *prune* any branches that no longer exist on the remote branch. So by executing `git fetch --prune origin` or `git fetch -p` the remote branch `origin/featureX` will be removed too.

Btw. if you want to remove a branch from a remote repository, you will have to push an “empty” branch to it, e.g. `git push origin :branchname` will remove the remote branch `origin/branchname` both locally and on the remote itself.

Comment: `git push origin :branchname` did delete the remote branch, but not the local branch.  I can still re-push `branchname` or work on it locally. What am I missing? I am on GitHub

Comment: @Rafs Removing the branch from the remote will only remove it there (but also your _local_ remote branch that reflects the remote’s version). Your local branch is untouched. You will have to remove that using e.g. `git branch -d branchname`

Comment: I get you now, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

## It means prune

[git fetch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) has the option to prune remote branches, that means for example:

```
$ git branch -a
develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/feature/deleted-last-week
remotes/origin/master
```

If the branch `feature/deleted-last-week` nolonger exists on the remote (because someone else deleted it already), running `fetch -p` will remove the local reference to it:

```
$ git fetch -p
remote: Counting objects: 751, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (346/346), done.
remote: Total 697 (delta 399), reused 632 (delta 337)
Receiving objects: 100% (697/697), 785.97 KiB | 377 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (399/399), completed with 27 local objects.
From github.com:AD7six/project
   3ed9793..dece27d  develop    -> origin/develop
   e4b5ae6..94053fd  master     -> origin/master
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/feature/deleted-last-week
$ git branch -a
develop
master
remotes/origin/HEAD
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

as it no longer exists on the remote. Pruning a remote can also be called explicitly as [git remote prune](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

Answer (score 8):

Did you trying looking at the help for `fetch`?  `git help fetch` shows:

```
-p, --prune
    After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no
    longer exist on the remote.
```

Typically, when you fetch any new references or updates are made to your `refs/remote/<remote-name>` area, with the exception of deleting references.  The `-p` option ask `fetch` (and `git remote update`) to go ahead and delete any remote references that no longer exist on the remote.  `git remote prune` will also remove deleted branches.

For instance, say there is a remote branch `foo`.  In your local repository, a reference at `refs/remote/origin/foo` is kept.  The someone deletes the `foo` branch.  The next time you run `git fetch`, your reference still remains intact.  If you run `git fetch -p` instead, you'll see that `refs/remote/origin/foo` is removed.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `git remote prune` and `git fetch -p`. You say that the first one will "also remove deleted branches", isn't that exactly what the second command is doing?

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo Nope. :-)  `git remote prune` only looks for the presence of the branches on the remote, and if they're missing on the remote then they'll be removed locally (from under refs/remote).  `git fetch -p` will grab new data but also run the pruning step.  So they're slightly different.

Comment: So `git fetch -p` = `git remote prune` + `git fetch`?

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo that's a reasonable way of thinking about it, though I would've stated it the other way around: `git fetch -p` = `git fetch` + `git remote prune` (the fetch happens before the pruning)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers explain what `git fetch --prune` does, but there is one case where it needs to be a bit more precise: when the there is nothing to fetch (no new refs) from the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)**.
In that case, it does prune the [remote tracking branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309) (from `/remotes/anUpstreamRepo/*`), but it didn't say what upstream repo was the cause of said pruning.

This is fixed by [commit 4b3b33a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b3b33a747c325f76b1f6eef89c231609dd4d361) by [Tom Miller (tmiller)](https://github.com/tmiller) for git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014):

### `fetch --prune`: always print header url

> If "`fetch --prune`" is run with no new refs to fetch, but it has refs to prune. Then, the header url is not printed as it would if there were new refs to fetch.
>
> Output before this patch:

```
$ git fetch --prune remote-with-no-new-refs
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/world
```

> Output after this patch:

```
$ git fetch --prune remote-with-no-new-refs
From https://github.com/git/git
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/test
```