# git fetch --all vs git fetch -p | What is the difference?

Tags: git

What is the difference between the following git commands?

```
git fetch --all
```

and

```
git fetch -p
```

Running them from the command line looks like they do the same thing.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'git fetch -p' means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832850/what-does-git-fetch-p-means)

Comment: As everyone else said, `--all` just means *all remotes*. How many remotes do you have? If you have only one, "all" remotes is the same as "my one remote", so `--all` has no effect. If you have two or more, Git will fetch from each one. Adding `-p` will cause fetch to prune as it goes, so it will fetch-and-prune from each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

1. `git fetch --all`: Fetch all remotes.
2. `git fetch -p`:  remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote before fetching

You may be seeing the exact same thing because your repo may not have anything to prune.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to run git fetch --all -p ?

Comment: @user1941537 It should be possible as the same documentation link shows that you can use `git fetch --all [options]`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`-p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--p) (or the `--prune`) flag implies that pruning should be done on references that no longer exists on the remote, as documented in the [documentation for `git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote.

On the other hand, the [`--all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---all) flag simply implies that all remotes should be fetched.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to run git fetch --all -p ?

Comment: @user1941537 I don’t see why not