# Git has some heavy files, I want to clean this

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm pretty new with git overall, and I'm still learning to have a good methodology with it. There's a few files within my git that I see we're a bit more heavy to handle than I expected. My repo is getting heavy because of this.

Essentially, I'm working on a VFX pipeline, and there's this certain plugin (let's call it MyPlugin)that is frequently updated that I kept updating, which is ok, but I was including it within my commits. Fortunately it is always within the same folder "MyPlugin/" (at the root of my git). Everytime I updated the version, I create a new subfolder with the version name. If v1.2 was released, I deleted the folder "MyPlugin/v1.1" and created folder "MyPlugin/v1.2".

I'd like to remove all of it from all my repo's history to handle it differently so it doesn't get so heavy.
Also note, that, as I work alone on this, there's only two branches currently running: "dev" and "master".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BFG](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#purging-a-file-from-your-repositorys-history) to remove large files from history.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `git gc` command to do some housekeeping and clean up the repository, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Answer (score 0):

Use `git fetch -p` which will *prune* any un-needed branches. See this SO [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833002/285795).