# Git two remotes set to the same endpoint, but are on different commits?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Both of my remotes are the same location

[image]

So how is it possible that they're at different commits?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

What you see are [remote tracking branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309), as memorized *locally* in your repo.

They represent the commit as seen the *last time* you fetch from those remotes.

If you fetch from origin earlier, and then fetch from heroku more recently, that would explain the difference.