# How to merge one remote branch into another remote branch?

Tags: git

I would like to know how to merge one remote branch into another remoter branch and have the previous one removed right after the merge applied.

Comment: The other remote branch would be from the same remote ?

Comment: Yep. Exactly the same remote.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From what I understand, you have one remote **foo**, containing **branch_1** and **branch_2**.
First, we can't do merge operation remotly. 
We have to track the remote repository, do the operation we want locally (such as merging branches) and then push our new snapshot to the server.

Ie:

- *git clone [repo_adress]*

You are on the master branch.

- You can then checkout or create other branches and do your work in it.

Now suppose we have the two branches **branch_1** and **branch_2**. You want to **merge branch_1 into branch_2 and then delete branch_1**.

You checkout to branch_2 and then merge branch_1 with it:

```
$ git checkout branch_2
$ git merge branch_1
```

From there either the merge is smooth or you've got conflict.
Once the merge is done, you can delete the merged branch i.e *branch_1* by doing:

```
$ git branch -d branch_1
```

And then push your work:

```
$ git push
```

In case branch_2 doesn't exist on the remote, you've got to create it:

```
$ git push -u foo branch_2
```

Note that deleting branch_1 locally doesn't delete it remotely (considering that it exists on the remote).
To do so, we are going to say to git: "*push nothing to the branch i want to delete*" ie:

```
$ git push remote_name :branch_name
```

To read like *git remote push remote_name "nothing":branch_name.*

Now is there any mean to do it automatically?

I don't know (although I would investigate post merge "git hook"), but I'm not sure we ought to wish it. Deleting branches on remote is somewhat hazardous. Doing so manually is a good way to be sure of what we are doing.

Comment: Then how does the 'Merge' functionality on Bitbucket work? The reviewer reviews the PR changes and after approving he just clicks on 'Merge' and the branches is merged remotely. If I refresh the local SourceTree, I see incoming changes from the remote.

Comment: Yes. You're right. At the time I answered I was focused on what 'possibly' happens under the hood on the git repository side and proposed it as a 'possible' answer
A more practical answer to the question is like you suggest.
You create a MR/PR on the repo side and check the "delete branch after merge" box. Thx for raising the point! @TejasChandrashekhar

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to the tracking branch(**a local branch which represents your remote branch**) in which you want to merge another branch by using the following command

```
git checkout origin/name_of_your_branch
```

After that merge the another remote branch

```
git merge origin/brach_name_you_wanted_to_merge
```

After that, if any conflicts occur, solve it. and after that just commit and push.

and now `checkout` to your local branch. by the following command

```
git checkout name_of_your_brnach
```

After that pull the origin by using `git pull` command. that's it.

Comment: Disambiguation for the ones who might not know: .. you mentioned "you can switch to the remote branch" which is inaccurate: that isn't a remote branch/it's still a local branch that is tracking a remote branch and needs network operators to be updated, such as pull, fetch or clone; .. all branches you have are **local** (even **tracking** branches that track the remote branches are still local) - so any checkouts you do switch between local branches or tracking branches - see here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/git-what-is-a-tracking-branch#answer-49755270

Answer (score 0):

You can pull them to your local. Do a merge and push it. To delete the redundant branch thereafter, just run

```
git push origin :<branch_to_delete>
```

For example, if you want to delete a branch A

```
git push origin :A
```