# How does git keep track of versions in the remote repository?

Tags: git

What I understand is that when make a push, my code in the remote repository gets updated. How does git actually keep track of the versions of the release (in context of git-flow).
Does the remote repository also pull any metadata along with my code or does it only pull code ?
I am relatively new to using git flow.

Comment: Git doesn't copy every file each time you push. It checks how the modifications you have made to existing files and stores that data.
https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It updates remote tracking branches (branches in the remotes namespace).

Those have the last SHA1 fetched from the remote in them.

See "[Git: What is a tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309)"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrbpy.png]

This isn't limited to "[git-flow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)", it is a basic git mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot of doubts. I think i get the gist of it. To keep up-to-date with changes in the remote repository, I use the git fetch origin command and this essentially updates my origin pointer and add my changes to any other changes in the remote repository.

Comment: @user3646965 yes, the idea is to keep an updated history of the remote repo in your local repo, in order for you to be autonomous, and work locally.