# deleting remote branch does not remove from GitHub

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a local branch, say `hotfix`. I put it up on GitHub using

```
$ git push -u origin hotfix
```

Then after merging the branch, I want to delete it. So I type

```
$ git branch -d hotfix
```

which deletes the branch locally. However, the remote branch is still on GitHub. Of course when I look at my remote branches,

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/hotfix
  origin/master
```

`hotfix` is still there. So then I try

```
$ git branch -r -d origin/hotfix
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

and `hotfix` is gone, as expected.

But then I go to GitHub and look at my branches, and `hotfix` is still there! How can I delete the remote `hotfix` from GitHub via the **command line**, without having to navigate to GitHub in my browser and delete it using the Website UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to push that deletion:

```
git push origin --delete hotfix
```

(any [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command would only have an effect on your local repo, not the GitHub remote one)

See more at "[How to delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309)".

A `git branch -d -r` only deletes a **[remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178852/6309)**, that is branches existing in the `remotes/origin` namespace of your local repo. GitHub (the actual remote repo) is never notified.

What you have "successfully" deleted is the "remote tracking branch" which is in your local repo and is meant to record the last SHA1 that you fetched from the upstream repo for that branch: that what a "remote tracking branch" is.

The correct sequence is:

```
git push origin --delete hotfix
git remote update --prune origin
```

That will delete the `hotfix` branch on the GitHub repo, and then delete any obsolete remote tracking branch in your repo.

Comment: How is this command different from `git branch --remote --delete origin/hotfix`?

Comment: @chharvey `git branch` is for modifying branches in your local repo: GitHub is never notified. See my edited answer.

Comment: @chharvey you have "successfully" deleted a remote tracking branch (which is in your repo in order to record the last SHA1 f that branch fetched on the remote repo), not the branch on the actual remote repo.

Comment: @chharvey conclusion: a remote (tracking) branch in your local repo isn't the same as a branch in your remote repo.

Comment: Got it. One last question: when I use `git push origin -d hotfix`, should I be on branch `hotfix` or on `master`?

Comment: @chharvey on any branch, it doesn't matter: it will influence only the upstream repo (GitHub). Your local repo won't notice it until you prune your "remotes" (that is the fetched references you have of your remote).