# Delete a remote branch with the same name as tag

Tags: git

I have a branch and a tag by the name `3.0.0`. Now how do i only delete the branch not the tag.

I tried

```
git push origin --delete 3.0.0
error: dst refspec 3.0.0 matches more than one.
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can push the full *branch* [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#_deleting_references):

```
git push origin :refs/heads/3.0.0
# shorter:
git push origin :heads/3.0.0

git push --delete refs/heads/3.0.0
# shorter
git push -d refs/heads/3.0.0
```

That would reference only a branch, not a tag (`refs/tags/3.0.0`).

Here [the refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt) has no source in front of the '`:`': that means deletion.

> Because the refspec is `<src>:<dst>`, by leaving off the `<src>` part, this basically says to make the topic branch on the remote "*nothing*", which **deletes** it.

I mentioned the [alternative `--delete` syntax here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216793/6309): [`git push -d`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--d).

Comment: I wouldn't say "try". Besides the slightly shorter ref `heads/3.0.0` this is the only way that has to work.

Comment: @try-catch-finally OK. I have amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I wouldn't say "the only way" [:-)  `git push --delete refs/heads/3.0.0` or `git push --delete heads/3.0.0`  should also work...

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I had checked out the branch first - why is that?

Comment: @zb226 Because the refspec (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch-ltrefspecgt) references HEAD by default when there is noting before the '`:`'.  You need to checkout the branch for HEAD to reference it.

Comment: @zb226 I have edited the answer to make that refspec clearer.

Comment: Make sure you don't add a `--delete` to this, like I did... It didn't look like `git push origin :heads/branchname` would delete a branch, but sure enough, it does.

Comment: @Sinjai Isn't the all point of the `:heads/branchname` syntax mentioned in my answer above to delete a branch? (`--delete` or no `--delete`)

Comment: @VonC Yes! But I just now discovered that very easy to miss syntax.

Comment: @VonC your answer goes into some detail about '`:`' meaning `HEAD` without stating that it also implies deletion - in fact, it doesn't even mention deletion except implicitly through the question, hence Sinjai and others' confusion. From the linked reference: "Because the refspec is `<src>:<dst>`, by leaving off the `<src>` part, this basically says to make the topic branch on the remote nothing, which deletes it."

Comment: @Tydaeus Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have updated this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

I came  here looking for a way to delete remote **tag** with same name as branch. Following from the Giants comments above, I found this worked:

```
git push <remote> :refs/tags/<mytag>
# or
git push origin :tags/<mytag>
```

The empty string to the left of the colon causes the remote reference to be deleted.

Comment: Could you explain how this delete a tag? It doesn't have the delete option or anything named delete?

Comment: The empty string to the left of the colon causes the remote reference to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The `--delete` option works for this purpose as long as you specify the ref you're deleting unambiguously:

```
git push origin --delete refs/tags/<tagname>
```

Or for a branch:

```
git push origin --delete refs/heads/<branchname>
```