# GitK shows remote/origin/master as behind master, but git status and other commands insist that everything is up to date

Tags: git, github

From when I started committing this morning, my master pointer has been advancing but my remote/origin/master pointer has not.  However, when I use the command line to check where remote origin is (`ls-remote origin`) as I've seen recommended on similar questions, The SHA1 returned is not the one of the commit that the remote/origin/master pointer indicates, but the one that master indicates.  When I try `git pull`, something else I saw recommended, I'm told that I'm already up to date.

Here is what gitk is currently showing (couldn't post an image)

- master
- 
- 
- 
- remotes/origin/master

I am the only person working on this code and very new to git and to version control in general.

Update:

Other things I've tried:

- Tried `git push`, which gives me the message that everything is up-to-date
- Tried `git fetch`, which does not change what I see in gitk (also tried `git fetch origin`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The opposite of `push` is not really `pull`, it's `fetch`.  In particular, `git pull` is essentially `git fetch` plus an extra step, `git merge` or `git rebase`.  This matters more if you have an older version of git, because:
2. If your git is older than 1.8.5 (my guess is that yours is), using `git pull` runs `git fetch` in such a way that the `fetch` step does *not* update the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.  However, if you run `git fetch origin` manually, it *will* update the remote-tracking branch (to the SHA-1 you see with `git ls-remote`), which will make your `gitk` display correct.
3. This seems particularly odd because `git push` *should* update your remote-tracking branch, so that after `git push origin master` tells you that everything is up to date, `gitk` should now see the update, as if you had run `git fetch origin`.  (This is true even with older git variants.  The change in git 1.8.5 was to make the fetch-run-by-pull update the remote-tracking branches, to eliminate this one oddity.)

(If you have a newer version of git, the `fetch` that `pull` runs should update the remote-tracking branches, and this whole question should not arise in the first place.)

---

Edit: as seen in comments below, the problem turned out to be a missing `fetch` specification in the repository's config file.  How *that* got created is still a mystery: normally, either the initial clone, or adding a remote named `origin`, will add the correct `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` line.  Should that line go missing, however, you must put it back to get the remote-tracking branches updated.

Comment: Okay, I just tried git fetch origin, still no effect.

Comment: That's particularly weird.  What does `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` produce?  (It *should* be `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and if it's something else that might explain this.)

Comment: When I use `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` nothing happens, I just get a new line to enter commands on.

Comment: Ah, very interesting.  That would explain the lack of updates.  Use either `git config --add` or `git config --edit` (or both) to add that as the `remote.origin.fetch` value (`--edit` brings up your editor, which I find is the easiest way to tweak things, but you might want to `git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'` first and then use `--edit` to view and/or fix typos).

Answer (score 2):

> my master pointer has been advancing but my remote/origin/master pointer has not.

That seems consistent with the local nature of a commit: it adds a new commit to your local branch (`master`), but does not change anything for your **[remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178852/6309)** (`origin/master`)

You would need to *push* ([`git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)) to your [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) in order for origin/master to change, and for git ls-remote to return a more recent commit SHA1.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, my git hub repository is up to date, looking at the website.  All of my new commits and changes are reflected.  When I use `git push origin master`, which is how I've always pushed, I'm told that everything is up to date.

Comment: As usual, your answer is correct. However I think that a short note on `git fetch` (along the lines of what you have already said about `git push`) would improve it.

Comment: @Chris I agree. I believe torek's answer took care of the git fetch part.