# push local branch to remote repository but download fails in git

Tags: git

i created the bare --bare project in gerrit

in my local git repository I can see

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/devel/bsp/master
  remotes/origin/devel/bsp/kernel-3.10-dev
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/task/adv/kernel
```

after that i used below push command like

```
$git push --all ssh://admin@localhost:29418/kernel-test
```

I can see in gerrit server gerrit/kernel-test

```
$git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/devel/bsp/master
  remotes/origin/devel/bsp/kernel-3.10-dev
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/task/adv/kernel
```

but when I do git clone for the same project , then I only can see

```
$git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I cant find remotes/origin/task/adv/kernel , remotes/origin/devel/bsp/kernel-3.10-dev and other branches

Comment: Does `git fetch --all` help?

Comment: did you clone with --single-branch?

Comment: i tried like below which worked well for me 


one time for clone/create the repositary :
git clone ssh://localhost1:29418/gerrit/kernel –mirror

git remote add new-origin ssh://localhost2:29418/repo/gerrit/kernel

git checkout –b kernel-test  remote/origin/master

git push --all new-origin

for push  the code from server to local

git fetch origin 

git fetch new-origin

git merge master kernel-test

git push --all new-origin

Answer (score 0):

Note that cloning the `gerrit/kernel-test` repo would absolutely bring only `remotes/origin/master`: only the local branches of `gerrit/kernel-test` are replicated as [remote tracking branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309) in the new clone.
And `gerrit/kernel-test` only has one local branch (`master`). All the others are its own remote tracking branches (tracking the local branches of your local repo).
The [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) of `master` is `remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: i tried like below which worked well for me 


one time for clone/create the repositary :
git clone ssh://localhost1:29418/gerrit/kernel –mirror

git remote add new-origin ssh://localhost2:29418/repo/gerrit/kernel

git checkout –b kernel-test  remote/origin/master

git push --all new-origin

for push  the code from server to local

git fetch origin 

git fetch new-origin

git merge master kernel-test

git push --all new-origin

Comment: @user2186338 the push --all would only push local branches. And a clone --mirror doesn't create local branches. You would need http://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309