# wchich one is tracking branch: origin/master or master

Tags: git, git-branch

I read [What is a tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/what-is-a-tracking-branch) and I am not sure wchich exactly master or origin/master is tracking branch or maybe both of them are

Answer (score 1):

`master` is a *local* branch.

`origin/master` is a *remote-tracking* branch.

A *tracking* branch is a local branch associated with another branch (usually a remote-tracking branch). Operations like `git status`, when reporting on the tracking branch, will indicate whether the branch is ahead of or behind the branch it tracks.

When you clone a repository, `master` is usually created as a tracking branch associated with `origin/master`, which itself is the branch `master` on the remote repository named `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

The word *tracking*, in Git, is badly overloaded—perhaps worse than the word *branch*, or perhaps just about the same.

The Git documentation uses the phrase *remote-tracking branch name* to describe names like `origin/master`.  Note that this phrase literally requires *all four words* in it, but because humans are humans, they tend to shorten it to *remote-tracking branch*.  I like to shorten it to *remote-tracking name* because it is not a *branch* name in one very important sense.<sup>1</sup>

Note that this phrase uses the word *tracking* as an adjective.<sup>2</sup>  The verb form, *to track*, is also used with branches: we say that a branch name such as `master` *tracks* the name `origin/master` if the name `origin/master` is set as the *upstream* of the name `master`.  Each (local) branch name can have one upstream set.  That is, a branch either has an upstream–e.g., `master` typically has `origin/master` as its upstream—or it has no upstream at all.  Having an upstream makes some Git operations more convenient or pleasant.

Meanwhile, `master` is a branch name.  We (and Git) sometimes use the phrase *local branch* to emphasize that this branch name is specific to this one particular Git repository.  The word *branch* in Git is, however, ambiguous: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

I strongly dislike the shortened phrase *tracking branch* because it's incredibly unclear whether someone is saying *tracking branch* as shorthand for a *remote-tracking name* (`origin/master`), or as shorthand for *setting the upstream of a branch* (setting `master` to "track" `origin/master`).  Or, as [chepner notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61783494/1256452), it can be used to refer to a branch that has such an upstream!  I recommend avoiding this phrase.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that the verb form of *track* is *also* used with file names.  File `README.md` is *tracked* if that file's name is in Git's *index*.

The index itself actually has three names: *index*, which is the one I just used, but also *staging area* and—rarely these days—*cache*.  You didn't ask about the index, but it's worth mentioning because any file that is *in* the index is a *tracked file*, which is another way the word *track* is used.

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, `git checkout origin/master` puts you in *detached HEAD* mode, because `origin/master` is not a *branch name*.

<sup>2</sup>Technically this is a *gerund* (a verb being used as a noun) that is being modified to become an adjective.  The same verb can, in other circumstances, be a *present participle*.  See, e.g., https://medium.com/@engtuto1/can-gerunds-be-also-used-as-adjectives-89e5698411f3