# Github checkout to a remote branch

Tags: git, github

[image]

I am currently on the master branch of my repo. How do I switch to the `remotes/OriginalRepo/master` branch? `git checkout remotes/OriginalRepo/master` does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/what-is-a-tracking-branch)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you did a `pull` and you're up to date , you can do: `git checkout --track remotes/OriginalRepo/master`

Comment: It get error: A branch named 'master' already exists. @dejdej

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

You will need to make your own branch name.  Because you already have one branch named `master`, you'll have a problem.  There's no single correct solution, but consider deleting your existing `master`, if you don't need it.  Then you can use [dejdej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008699/1256452).

If you want to keep your existing `master`, come up with another name for this branch.  Let's say you choose `xyzzy` for some reason:

```
git checkout -b xyzzy OriginalRepo/master
```

will do the trick here.  You may eventually run into some more issues, but we'll leave them for another answer.

#### Long

Git documentation uses terms that I find confusing (both to me and to others when I am showing them how to use Git).  So instead of Git's terminology, I use my own:

- A *branch name* is a name that you have available for *you* to use.  In your output image,<sup>1</sup> `Relayout`, `getStarted`, `master`, and `signup` are *branch names*.  These are all in green (well, there's one weirdness mentioned in the next bullet point).
- A *remote-tracking name* is a name that your Git has created, in your repository, based on a *branch name* that your Git saw int some *other* Git repository.  In your image, `remotes/OriginalRepo/Relayout`, `remotes/OriginalRepo/getStarted`, and so on are remote-tracking names.  These are all in red, except for the weirdness right after `remotes/origin/HEAD`.

So we have two kinds of names here: *branch* names and *remote-tracking* names.<sup>2</sup>  The remote-tracking names are your Git's way of remembering *some other* Git's branch names, but they're not *branch* names themselves.

Note how in your `git branch -a` output all the remote-tracking names start with `remotes/`.  If you run `git branch -r`, you'll get the same set of remote-tracking names, but this time Git will leave off the word `remotes/`.  You'll have `OriginalRepo/Relayout` and so on.  These are still the same names!  Git has merely left out some stuff that we didn't need this time.

*All* of Git's names—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and other special purpose names like the one for `git stash` and the ones for `git bisect` and so on—work the same way and use a general mechanism.  Git's term for this is *refs* or *references*.  They start with `refs/` and then normally have another word, like `remotes/`, that defines which *group of names* they go into, i.e., which *kind* of name they are.  Branch names all start with `refs/heads/`, tag names all start with `refs/tags/`, and remote-tracking names all start with `refs/remotes/`.  Whenever it's clear enough—which is almost always—you can leave off the `refs/` part, and whenever it's clear enough, you can also leave off the `heads/` or `tags/` or `remotes/` part.

So that's why `origin/master` is sufficient: as long as you didn't make your own *branch* name `origin/master`,<sup>3</sup> `origin/master` will be short for your `refs/remotes/origin/master` remote-tracking name.  But if you like, you can write `remotes/origin/master` or `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  It sometimes feels a bit like [Stella](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stella_Mudd) calling out [Harcourt Fenton Mudd](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Harcourt_Fenton_Mudd).

---

<sup>1</sup>StackOverflow guidelines generally ask that you post cut-and-pasted text rather than images, but in this particular case, the image has the advantage of retaining the colors.

<sup>2</sup>Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find that the word *branch* in the middle of this phrase just makes everything messier and more confusing.  They're not actually *branch* names—well, not in *your* Git repository, anyway.

<sup>3</sup>Don't do it.  *Git* won't get confused as to which one is which, but *you* will.  But if you did it just because I said not to, you can use `heads/origin/master` or `refs/heads/origin/master` to refer to the *branch* name, and `remotes/origin/master` or `refs/remotes/origin/master` to refer to the *remote-tracking* name.  Well, mostly.  Some commands don't like the extra verbiage!

---

#### Checkout, branches, and detached HEADs

With the terminology out of the way, let's look at the question itself again:

> How do I switch to the `remotes/OriginalRepo/master` branch?

You don't.  It's not a *branch*.  It's a remote-tracking name.

> `git checkout remotes/OriginalRepo/master` does not work

But `git checkout remotes/OriginalRepo/master` *does* work, for some definition of "work".  It's just that it gets you what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.

What's going on here seems complicated at first, but it's not, really.  The trick is that *Git does not care about branches*.  Git cares about *commits*.  Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—exist to help us, and Git, *find* the commits.  What matters is not the branch names, though, but rather the commits themselves.

The `git checkout` command actually has multiple functions.  In fact, it has too many functions: in Git 2.23 and later, it's been split into what is roughly two halves.  One is `git switch` and the other is `git restore`.  The existing `git checkout` command remains, and still does both sets of jobs.  We won't look at one entire set at all, and will concentrate here only on the other set: the half of the jobs that are now done with `git switch`.

These jobs involve *extracting a commit*, and also *setting up your HEAD*.  To get any work done in Git, we *have* to extract a commit.  Let's look at why this is the case.

#### Commits

A Git commit is a real, tangible thing.  To access a commit in Git, we must tell Git its true name.  But the true name of a commit is a big ugly random-looking hash ID, like [`faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475) for instance.  There's no way for a *human* to remember these things.  Fortunately we don't have to; but we'll get to that in a moment.  First, let's look at what's *inside* one of these things.

A Git commit consists of two parts:

- There is a snapshot of all the files that Git knew about, at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  This snapshot is completely, totally read-only, and the files stored inside it are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, that only Git itself can use.
- Besides the snapshot—the main data—each commit contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  The metadata include the name and email address of the person who made the commit, the date-and-time of the commit, and so on.

One crucial piece of information that Git sticks into the metadata for each commit is the raw hash ID of some *previous* commit, or in some cases, more than one previous commit.  This is how Git stores history.  The *latest* commit has inside it the hash ID of the *next-to-latest* commit.  That commit has inside it the hash ID of an earlier commit.  This repeats, so that in a simple case of a nice linear chain of commits, we have something we can draw like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the latest commit.  By giving Git the raw hash ID `H`, Git can see what's in that commit: all the source (in the frozen, Git-only format), and also the metadata, including the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

This earlier commit hash ID allows Git to *find* `G`, and extract it—all of it, or just the metadata, or whatever—which in turns allows Git to find `F`, and so on.  So this means that in order to use the entire chain of commits, all we *really* need is some way to remember hash ID `H`.

To use the *files* from the commit, though, we'll need to have Git extract them.  Git will copy those files *out* of the commit, restoring them to normal everyday files, which we can actually use to do work.  The process of extracting some commit is the main work of `git checkout` (or in 2.23-and-later, `git switch`).

The files you'll work with, extracted from some commit, are in what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  There's always—well, almost always—one initial work-tree for a repository; you can add more, with `git worktree`, later, if you like.

#### Branch names

Now that we know how commits work and what they do for us—store files and act as history, with these backwards-pointing chains of commits—*now* we can finally understand how Git uses a branch name.  A branch name like `master` or `signup` simply holds the hash ID of *one* commit.  By definition, that commit is the *last* commit that is "on that branch".  Let's draw this—it probably isn't right, but it's meant to give the flavor of how these work:

```
          I--J   <-- signup
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- Relayout
```

Here, we show six commits—there are probably lots more before commit `G`—where each commit points backwards to one previous commit: commit `J`, which is the latest on `signup`, points backwards to commit `I`.  Commit `I` points backwards to commit `H`.  (The connecting lines really should have arrow-heads pointing backwards, but I can't draw those very well on StackOverflow.)  Commit `L` points back to `K`, which also points back to `H`.  Commit `H` points back to `G`, which points back to whatever else might exist.

An interesting feature of Git is that the commits that are on `master` are also on *both of the other two branches*.  Git says that a commit is "on" some branch if, by starting with the branch name and the commit it selects, we can work backwards to find some other commit.

We can also have more than one branch name point to one particular commit.  For instance, in this or some other repository, we could have:

```
...--P--Q   <-- br1, br2, br3
```

Here, *all three branch names* select the *same* commit, commit `Q`.  The commits leading up to and including `Q` are on all three branches.

Whenever we have more than one branch name, though, we need one more piece of information.  In particular, *how do we know which branch name we are using?*  Git's answer to this is the special name `HEAD`, which must be written in all capitals like this.<sup>4</sup>  We "attach" the name `HEAD` to exactly one branch name:

```
          I--J   <-- signup
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- Relayout
```

When `HEAD` is attached to `master` like this, `git branch` shows an asterisk next to the name `master`, to note that we're currently using the name `master` to find the commit whose hash ID is `H`.

Whenever we make a *new* commit, Git makes the commit itself—the snapshot with its metadata—so that the *new* commit points back to the current commit, as found using the name `HEAD`.  The new commit gets a new, unique, big ugly hash ID.  Git immediately *stores* the new hash ID in the *current branch name*.  So if we have the above, and make new commit `N`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- signup
         /
...--G--H--N   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- Relayout
```

Note how no existing commit has changed.  No commit *can* ever change: that's how Git makes sure we can always get back anything we committed.  All we did was add the new commit, `N`, that points back to existing commit `H`, and make the *name* `master` point to new commit `N`.  The name `master` is the one that got updated—and `N`'s parent is `H`—*because* `HEAD` is attached to `master`.

---

<sup>4</sup>On a typical macOS system, you can *sometimes* get away with writing `head`, in lowercase, instead of `HEAD` in all-capitals.  This breaks once you start adding more work-trees, so don't get into the habit.  If you don't like typing `HEAD` because of all the uppercase, consider using its one-character synonym `@`.

---

#### Detached HEAD

If you run:

```
git checkout OriginalRepo/master
```

you get, as we noted earlier, a "detached HEAD".  That's because, just like branch names, remote-tracking names point to one commit—but unlike branch names, Git won't let you *attach* the special name `HEAD` to a *remote-tracking* name, and `OriginalRepo/master` is one of those.

So, suppose we have, say, this:

```
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master
      \
       H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we run `git checkout` on the name `OriginalRepo/master`, we're asking Git to extract commit `G`.  That's the commit whose hash ID is stored in the name `OriginalRepo/master`.  But Git can't *attach* `HEAD` to that, because that's not a *branch* name, it's a remote-tracking name instead.  So we get:

```
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master, HEAD
      \
       H   <-- master
```

In this detached-HEAD mode, we have the *commit* extracted.  We can even make a *new* commit `N` just like before, but if we do, *the special name `HEAD`* gets updated directly:

```
       N   <-- HEAD
      /
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master
      \
       H   <-- master
```

If we use `git checkout master`, say, to *re-attach* `HEAD` to a branch name, we end up with this:

```
       N   ???
      /
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master
      \
       H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Commit `N` *still exists*.  It's still there in your repository!  But there is no *name* for it.  The only name that will work is the raw hash ID.  Did you write it down somewhere?

#### The solution to this dilemma is to add a branch name

If we're on commit `N`, having made it, we can just *add a new branch name right then and there:*

```
       N   <-- xyzzy, HEAD
      /
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master
      \
       H   <-- master
```

We can do this with, e.g., `git branch xyzzy`.  That creates a new branch name `xyzzy` pointing to the current commit (by writing the current / `HEAD`-commit hash ID into the new name).  We can then attach `HEAD` to `xyzzy` if we like, with `git checkout xyzzy`.  We don't change *commits*—we were already on commit `N`—but now we have:

```
       N   <-- xyzzy (HEAD)
      /
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master
      \
       H   <-- master
```

and any *new* commits we make will update the name `xyzzy`.

Or, if we don't yet have commit `N` and just have this:

```
...--G   <-- OriginalRepo/master
      \
       H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We can tell Git to extract commit `G` and make it current, then add a new branch name `xyzzy` and get on it.  We could do this with:

```
git checkout OriginalRepo/master
git branch xyzzy
git checkout xyzzy
```

or we can shorten this to:

```
git checkout -b --no-track xyzzy OriginalRepo/master
```

You might say: *wait, what is this `--no-track` thing?*  It's not really clear whether you should use it, but probably you *shouldn't* use it.  I put it in because this makes the `git checkout -b` act *exactly the same* as the three command variant, `git checkout` (for detached HEAD) followed by `git branch` followed by `git checkout` (to attach HEAD).  This gets us into our last little wrinkle.

#### Branches have upstreams

In Git, each branch name can have one *upstream* set.  The upstream setting of a branch is not crucial.  In fact, you can have branches that *don't* have any upstream.  The purpose of setting an upstream is to make some things convenient.

There's another name for the upstream setting stuff.  It is a terrible name, but it shows up in Git because of the `--track` and `--no-track` options.  The bad name for this is to call a branch with an upstream set, a *tracking branch*.

There are a lot of reasons that this is a terrible name.  The most important one, I think, is that Git has the notion of *tracked files* vs *untracked files*, and this is completely separate from branch upstream settings.  There are also those remote-tracking names (or "remote-tracking branch names" if you prefer the Git terminology), and they're also different from upstreams.  So let's use the new term, *upstream*, to talk about the upstream of a branch.

Typically, the upstream of a branch name like `master` is a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`.<sup>5</sup>  This makes the `git status` command more useful, and makes it possible to run `git pull`, `git merge`, and `git rebase` without typing in as much stuff.  That's its main function, really.  Setting the upstream makes it easier to run other Git commands, and/or makes their output more useful.

But if the upstream of `master` is normally `origin/master`, for instance, what would be the pair of names for `OriginalRepo/master`?  Obviously, you should have another branch named `master` whose upstream is `OriginalRepo/master`.  But there are two problems:

- A branch name can only hold *one* hash ID.
- A branch name can only have *one* upstream.

Since the name `master` is the same as the name `master`, you'll have to break the symmetry here somehow.  You can use a silly name like `xyzzy` for one of these, for instance: `xyzzy` can store the same hash ID as `OriginalRepo/master`, and can have `OriginalRepo/master` as its upstream.  That solves all of those problems.<sup>6</sup>

The way to set, or unset, an upstream on an *existing* branch is to use `git branch`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=OriginalRepo/master xyzzy
```

sets the upstream of `xyzzy` to `OriginalRepo/master`.  Meanwhile:

```
git branch --unset-upstream xyzzy
```

strips out the upstream entirely (if you ever want to do that; there's sometimes reasons, but it's never *required*).

When you *create a new branch name* with `git checkout -b` or `git branch`, however, you get to choose whether the new name has an upstream already set.  The flag for this is `--track` or `--no-track`.  Using `--no-track` means *don't set up an upstream* and using `--track` means *do set up an upstream*.

So, if you *do* want to have `xyzzy` have `OriginalRepo/master` as its upstream:

```
git checkout -b xyzzy --track OriginalRepo/master
```

does that explicitly.  The `--track` and `--no-track` are actually defaults, in a complicated way.  I'm going to leave out the full details as this answer is already too long.

---

<sup>5</sup>The reason these are called *remote-tracking names* in the first place is that Git has an entity called a *remote*.  A remote is mainly a short name, like `origin` or `upstream` or `OriginalRepo`, under which you can store a longer URL.  But Git then uses the remote name to construct the remote-tracking names, which track (i.e., remember the hash IDs from) the *branch* names in the Git that your Git reaches at that remote.  You can pretty easily get dizzy from all this stuff: a *remote* holds a URL; a *remote-tracking name* is built from a remote name plus a branch name; a branch name can have an upstream set, and is then sometimes said to be a "tracking branch"; and files are tracked or untracked, which has nothing to do with any of that!

<sup>6</sup>This does introduce one problem of its own, which is that one part of Git really wants the names to be symmetric.  In particular, if you ever want to use `git push` to send updates directly to `OriginalRepo`, *and* you have `push.default` set to `simple`, Git will demand that the upstream of `xyzzy` be `OriginalRepo/xyzzy`, not `OriginalRepo/master`.  But if you never need to push there, that's not going to be a stumbling block, and if you ever *do* need that, there are multiple ways around this problem.