# is it possible to change the default remote on git for any command

Tags: git

After adding a new remote.
I am trying to change the defaut remote for any git commands will be executed.
Not sure is it possible or the default remote is always related to branches.

Comment: What git commands do you mean? You can specify which remote a branch tracks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693588/what-is-a-tracking-branch

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default remote". As you say, a branch may have a certain remote branch as its "upstream", and you can find that out by saying `git branch -vv`