# git showing old remote branches

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I have executed `git remote rm origin` and I still get the following result.

[image: this]

Executing `git branch -r` returns no result, and when executing `git remote rm origin` again, I get

> Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'

I have also executed a `git gc --purge=now` and no result for the above issue. Any idea what could go wrong, and how to fix it?

`.git/config` contents

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[branch "master"]
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag =
```

That's the weird part, no `origin` nor `upstream` is defined

Comment: Let's dive under the hood a bit to try and figure this out. Can you post the contents of `.git/config` which is where the information about your remotes is stored.

Comment: I think there was a minor bug where the last config section was not deleted if empty, which may be your issue. Have a look at the config file (it's plain text) and see if you still have a [remote "origin"] section (as Peter L said). It may also be because of its use as a default.

Comment: That's the weird part, no origin nor upstream is defined

Comment: Then check the output of `git config --global -l` and `git config --system -l` just in case

Comment: `git config --global -l` returns `user.name` and `user.email` while `git config --system -l` at the end, returns `remote.origin.fetch` and `remote.upstream.fetch`

Comment: @VonC no update on the matter?

Comment: @w0rldart sorry, I missed your previous comment. I can assure you a system git config file should *never* include any `remote.origin` information. Can you do a `git config --system --edit` and manually remove the `[remote]` section? And see if that improves the situation? Note: I would still recommend that for the global config (`git config --global --edit`) in your specific case, just to clean up the remote `origin`. I will see the result in a few hours: time to go to bed for me.

Comment: @VonC Could it be related to Github client on Windows? I mean, I haven't done that manually, neither executing any command, so the only thing remaining is Github. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Executing `git branch -r` returns no result

So there isn't any [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch/1070851#1070851) fetched from any [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) remote repo.
But that has no bearing on the number of remote repo declared for your local repo: you could have 100 remotes repos declared, as long as no git fetch is done, a `git branch -r` would still return nothing.

> and when executing git remote rm origin again, I get

```
Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'
```

That is the standard message for saying that the remote you are trying to (again) delete doesn't exist.
The first `git remote rm origin` did work.

At this point, all what remains would be a remote named '`origin` ' (with a space at the end).
Or, as [Peter Lundgren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727593/peter-lundgren) and [Philip Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717355/philip-oakley) mention in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133992/git-showing-old-remote-branches/17135524#comment24798293_17133992), an empty extra entry in the `.git/config` file, named "`origin`", that you might need to manually delete.