# Error in git book or I misunderstood?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-pull, remote-branch

[Here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) you can read:

> Tracking Branches Checking out a local branch from a remote branch
>   automatically creates what is called a tracking branch. Tracking
>   branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a
>   remote branch. If you’re on a tracking branch and type git push, Git
>   automatically knows which server and branch to push to. Also, running
>   git pull while on one of these branches fetches all the remote
>   references and then automatically *merges in the corresponding remote
>   branch*.

Instead of *merges in the corresponding remote branch* shouldn't day *merge in the corresponding local branch*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

> Also, running `git pull` while on one of these branches fetches all the remote references and then automatically merges in the corresponding remote branch.

That should read as:

The git pull will update a "remote tracking branch", and merge those updates in a local branch tracking said remote tracking branch.

See the next section for an explanation of all those *different* "tracking" elements.

---

Note that the term "track" has been part of the most confusing ones in git, from [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) blog post "[The most confusing git terminology](http://longair.net/blog/2012/05/07/the-most-confusing-git-terminology/)".

#### “track” and “tracking”

> 1/ “track” as in “untracked files”
>
> To say that a file is tracked in the repository appears to mean that it is either present in the index or exists in the commit pointed to by HEAD.
>   You see this usage most often in the output of “`git status`”, where it will list “`untracked files`”:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
```

> 2. “`track`” as in “[remote-tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch/1070851#1070851)”

As a bit of background, you can think of a remote-tracking branch as a local cache of the state of a branch in a remote repository.
The most commonly seen example is `origin/master`, or, to name that ref in full, `refs/remotes/origin/master`.
Such branches are usually updated by `git fetch`.

> The sense of “track” in the phrase “remote-tracking branch” is indicating that the remote-tracking branch is tracking the state of the branch in the remote repository the last time that remote-tracking branch was updated.
>   So, you might say that `refs/remotes/origin/master` is tracking the state of the branch `master` in `origin`.
>
> The “tracking” here is defined by the refspec in the config variable `remote.<remote-name>.fetch` and the URL in the config variable `remote.<remote-name>.url`.
>
> 3. “track” as in “[`git branch –track foo origin/bar`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch.html)” or: “Branch `foo` set up to track remote branch `bar` from `origin`”
>
> Again, if you want to do some work on a branch from a remote repository, but want to keep your work separate from everything else in your repository, you’ll typically use a command like the following (or one of its many “Do What I Mean” equivalents):

```
git checkout --track -b foo origin/bar
```

> The sense of “track” both in the command and the output is distinct from the previous sense – it means that config options have been set that associate your new local branch with another branch in the remote repository.
>   The documentation sometimes refers to this relationship as making `bar` in `origin` “[upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)” of `foo`.
>   This “[upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)” association is very useful, in fact:
>
> - it enables nice features like being able to just type `git pull` while you’re on branch `foo` in order to fetch from `origin` and then merge from `origin/bar`.
> - It’s also how you get helpful messages about the state of your branch relative to the remote-tracking branch, like “`Your branch foo is 24 commits ahead of origin/bar and can be fast-forwarded`”.
>
> The tracking here is defined by config variables `branch.<branch-name>.remote` and `branch.<branch-name>.merge`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. [The book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) could lead to a confusion cos used in my opinion a no so clear definition. It named your *remote-tracking branch* as *remote branches* and your *bar in origin upstream of foo* concept as *tracking branch*.

Comment: @gsc-frank I agree, and this is the source for the section on "tracking" for Mark Longair's blog post. Here, a tracking branch is tracking a remote tracking branch. Meaning a local branch with an associated upstream branch is tracking said upstream branch, itself tracking a branch of an upstream repo!

Answer (score 1):

You have mistaken the italics here. The verb is "merges in" with emphasis on *in*. You read it as "merges into". Instead, read it as "merges in from the corresponding remote branch".

Comment: Italic fixed. Seem to me that could be then: *merges in the corresponding remote branch into the local tracking branch*, right? I just said that to confirm that I understand more than to propose a text change ;) Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the last sentence, I believe that to be correct.

For pushing:
*Corresponding local branch pushes to remote branch.*

For Fetching:
*Corresponding remote branch pushes to local branch.*

That's how I would interpret it.