# JGit: Push to specific branch

Tags: git, branch, push, jgit

I have two branches on github: master and development. 
I want to push a newly created file to the development branch.

```
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String localPath = "local";
    String remotePath = "https://github.com/some/git.git";
    Git.cloneRepository().setBranch("refs/heads/development").setURI(remotePath).setDirectory(new File(localPath)).call();
    Git localGit = Git.open(new File(localPath));         
    localGit.checkout().setName("origin/development").setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK).call();

    new File("local/test").createNewFile();

    localGit.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
    localGit.commit().setMessage("message").call();
    localGit.push().setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(user, password)).call();
```

What I get is a

```
  TransportException: Nothing to push.
```

What's the problem there?

**Update:**
I could make it work by removing the checkout command. As the clone already checks out the specified branch, which wasn't clear to me before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing a checkout of the `origin/development` (that is a [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070851/6309) of the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) '`origin`'), you have created a [**detached head**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714), that is a head associated with 0 *local* branch (ie, not with `refs/head/development`, but here with `refs/remotes/origin/development`)

That is why a `git push` returns "nothing to push", since no local branch has received any new commit to push.

You need to be sure of:

- having the local '`development`' branch checked out (which you did with `.setBranch("development")`, although I prefer, as in the [jgit clone test](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f3fc3797579ac0bf55648bad560e7daa5e6df9b5/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CloneCommandTest.java#L163), to use `.setBranch("refs/head/development")` to be sure to reference a local branch)
- making '`origin/development`' the upstream branch of '`development`'.
  Or at least, as in this [jgit push test](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f3fc3797579ac0bf55648bad560e7daa5e6df9b5/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L100), use the right refspec `development:development`.

Comment: Ok, so should a localGit.checkout().setName("origin/development").setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK).call(); do the trick?

Because even then I get the same error message: TransportException: Nothing to push.

Comment: Also, when I do git status I see that the head still is detached. I don't know how I can fix that.

Comment: When I look into HEAD it is ref: refs/heads/development before I do the checkout. After the checkout I have 5750afe0339795f1e31c5c229842636f7db53357 (which is the reason for the detached head, right?)

Comment: took me a little bit longer to completely understand and make it work, but you gave me all the info needed. Thanks!

Comment: @hansi great! removing the checkout is the easiest solution, and avoid checkout of a remote tracking branch (which is the surest way to get a detached head and "nothing to push")