# git push to the forked prj; pull request to a parent branch

Tags: git, push

When I forked the project initially and set up my env I had this.

```
> git branch -a

remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/upstream/master
```

I do not have "push" permission to the upstream project.  I must
send pull requests from my fork.

A week later a new branch was created for work on a specific enhancement to upstream.
The team may be working from this branch for many weeks.

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/upstream/new-project-feature
remotes/upstream/master
```

What is the appropriate way for me to setup and submit code to this branch?
This is what I have done.  Was it the proper thing to do?

```
git branch new-project-feature
git checkout new-project-feature
git rebase upstream/new-project-feature
.. code changes
.. commit
git push origin HEAD:new-project-feature
.. go to github and send the pull request.
```

How does the parent project know to merge the pull request to its 
new-project-feature branch?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a pull-request is:

- you work on a small enhancement that you would like to see merged into the upstream branch
- you push that enhancement to your fork (`origin`), and make the pull request from there

[image: fork]

BUT:

You should make that enhancement in a **dedicated branch**, *not* in the target branch.
That means, not in `master` or in `new-project-feature`: those are "target" branches which, in your fork, are there to *mirror* the **[`upstream` repo,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** to "**[remote track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070851/6309)**" `upstream/master` or `upstream/new-project-feature`.

So you should make one or *several* branches, each one for a small change you want to contribute to `new-project-feature`, push that one little branch "`small_change`", and make a pull request to `upstream/new-project-feature`.

You can regularly pull `upstream`, updating your local `new-project-feature` with the latest of upstream/new-project-feature.
You can then *rebase* your "small_changes" branch on top of the updated `new-project-feature` branch, and go on working on it.

Note that if `new-project-feature` changes in upstream *after* you already make your pull request from the fork, all you need to do is:

- fetch and update locally the `new-project-feature` branch
- rebase your `small_change` branch on top of new-project-feature
- check that everything still works
- `git push --force origin small_change`

The last forced push will automatically update your pull request: **you won't have to do a second pull request**.
See more at "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".