# Git: how to switch from branch X to Y?

Tags: git

For example, I clone step_06 of:

> git clone -b step_06 https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially

Now I want to replace step06's files with step07's files (on my machine).
So I did:

> git checkout -b step_07
>
> cd meteor-angular-socially
>
> git checkout -b step07
>
> Switched to a new branch 'step_07'

However **nothing actually changes in the folder/files**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing should be change if you haven't commit any changes to the branch. You can see the current branch you are working on by running `git branch`. In your case this should return `*step_07`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new local branch instead of switching to the one from the remote repo.

`git checkout step_07` should have been enough (from [`man git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to:

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

Make sure to do a `git fetch` first, in order to get all remote branches.

But in your case, add `git reset --hard origin/step_07`

Here are the [differences between `step_06` and `step_07`, as reported by GitHub](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially/compare/step_06...step_07).

Comment: thank you. it worked! can you please just clarify the command "git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>"?

Comment: also, If I make some change to the local branch but then I request another branch. can I preserve the changes I made?

Comment: @dragonmnl , If I make some change to the local branch but then I request another branch. can I preserve the changes I made? You would need to commit your local changes first. Then a checkout to another branch wouldn't lose those changes.

Comment: @dragonmnl see also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches for the remote tracking aspect (also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25097913/6309)